# I voted to close with the wrong duplicate. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, close-reasons, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

In an act of unmatched hypocrisy, I failed to properly search for a duplicate and ended up closing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741482/remove-the-first-git-commit-from-the-history) with [this near duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-amend-modify-change-the-first-root-initial-commit-in-git) rather than [this exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575694/can-i-remove-the-initial-commit-from-a-git-repo). Regardless of the nuances of this particular case, what should I do if I've closed with an obviously wrong duplicate *when the right duplicate hasn't been mentioned yet?* Since I can't change my vote, should I retract it, leave a comment, and hope others find the right duplicate? Flagging the question crosses my mind, but it seems inappropriate to ask a mod to handle this.

Like any question of this nature, I'll end it with a solemn, heartfelt, "*I'll be more careful next time!*" :)

Comment: What "hypocrisy" is there in this action?

Comment: If you have some regulars in a  chatroom you can organize a reopen and close team.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Closing someone's question as a duplicate carries at least a small undertone of "you should've searched the site properly first!" which I failed to do. :)

Comment: I am a prolific dupe-close-proposer, but whenever it comes up I always try to emphasize that (except in the case of _egregious_ duplication, for which I have a handy list of pre-formed "this is a duplicate of these 800 questions:...") it's generally okay to have posted a duplicate, and that my vote is not meant as castigation. Perhaps if you keep the "your answer is already ready already" aspect of duplication in mind you'll feel better about it.

Answer (score 11):

This happens occasionally, so don't worry about it. Flagging is exactly the correct action to take here; a moderator can very easily re-open and re-close the question with the correct dupe target.

Another good option is to ask someone with a gold tag badge to use [the dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/159251) to single-handedly re-open and re-close the question, if such a person has been seen in activity on the question, or if you can find one in a chat room.

If you need to flag, use a custom moderator flag and just explain that you linked the wrong duplicate, but that this other link is the one you meant to use and the right target. I did this myself a month or two ago:

[image]

Keep in mind that it may take several days for custom flags to be handled. In this case more so, since a mod without knowledge of the subject matter might leave it for another who has it. Be patient.

Until the flag is handled, it's good to leave a comment along the lines of "Oh, crap, this was closed wrongly! The correct dupe would be ______________. I've flagged for a mod to fix this."

Comment: Last time I did this, I got "declined - let's call it a wash since they basically attack the same thing, just on nuance" (this was on Meta, not sure if that makes a difference).

Comment: Or a mod without knowledge of the matter may just [decline your flag without really looking at it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252844/1269037).

Comment: Well, asking in a chat-room accepting such for help if it got closed is probably both more reliable and faster.

Comment: This answer (doubtless correct when posted) is not true today. If you flag for wrong duplicate, you'll get the flag declined with "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"

Comment: Sorry to hear that, @AndrewSpencer; it's been quite a while since I've raised this kind of flag. Note that flag handling is not necessarily uniform: mods sometimes differ in their opinions about how to deal with a particular situation. Still flag handling does seem to have changed some over the last year or two, but I could be imagining that...

Comment: @JoshCaswell they seem to have a checkbox that adds the comment automatically, since it's always the same wording.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's one of the standard flag decline reasons.

Answer (score 6):

If my vote wasn't the fifth, personally I would retract my vote (although I couldn't vote again), and leave a comment pointing to the correct duplicate. I think it's worth doing this rather than let it point to the incorrect duplicate, as if closed, it might be a target of *reopen* votes when it's still a duplicate, actually.

If it was the fifth vote, I'd just let a comment saying I was the author of the close vote pointing to *X* question as the duplicate, that it's wrong, that it shouldn't be followed and that I meant the other one to be the correct one.

Comment: How does one retract a vote?

Comment: Simply click again on `Close` and you'll see the `Retract` button there.