# Incorrect/wrong duplicate question

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347471/caret-position-in-pixels-in-an-input-type-text-not-a-textarea) is about finding the caret position in pixels in an `<input type="text"`. It's indeed a duplicate, but not of the [question currently marked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes) as a duplicate (which refers to text areas).

I've already flagged it, but my flag was declined on the grounds that *"flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*.

So here I am, attempting again to make a moderator aware of content that requires their intervention, [as advised by Josh Caswell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252408/1269037).

The question should be marked as a duplicate of [Get cursor or text position in pixels for input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930578/get-cursor-or-text-position-in-pixels-for-input-element). I've already asked in Chat, but didn't manage to get people to vote to re-open, then to close. After being pestered in the comments below, I've already asked the existing closers (being labeled as "OCD" in the process), but [they can't vote to reopen either](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete/issues/16#issuecomment-41936902).

Please help me stop wasting time? :) Thanks!

Comment: No, the content **doesn't require moderator intervention**. Users can do this themselves. Vote to reopen, convince others to do the same, then vote to close as a dupe of the other post. Done.

Comment: Right, "done", very easy... hang out in a chatroom, canvas for 4 votes, convince them I'm right etc. I had voted already to have it reopened more than a month ago. I could use a helpful reopen vote from you a bit more than telling me to work my behind off while a moderator could do this in a snap, again, [as Josh has advised](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252408/1269037).

Comment: I didn't say it'd be easy, but it doesn't *require* moderator intervention either.

Comment: Fair enough. Do I get a reopen vote or not?

Comment: Wait, what? That post says: *Note: I don't want to know the position in characters. I want to know position in pixels.*, and it is closed as a dupe of a post that tells you how to do just that. You want to reclose it as a dupe of a post that tells you the position in characters instead? Why?

Comment: There is no comment on that post explaining to me and other voters why they should reopen either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: the screenshot of my two flags explains clearly why, but I've added [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347471/caret-position-in-pixels-in-an-input-type-text-not-a-textarea#comment35819429_13347471) as well.

Comment: Right, but that comment should have been on the post in the first place when you voted to reopen this before! How can you expect the rest of the reopen reviewers to follow your lead if you didn't actually tell why it was to be re-done?

Comment: That's why I flagged it for moderator attention - the flags explained perfectly clearly what the problem was. I didn't expect 4 other people (reopen reviewers) to waste their time listening to my pitch, voting to reopen, then voting to close again, when one moderator could just change the duplicate.

Comment: And I am far from a domain expert, so I may be missing something here. The OP emphatically tells us they are looking for pixel coordinates but the new dupe you are pointing us to talks about *character count*. Perhaps you need to spell out that it is still the right dupe target *because of x, y and z*.

Comment: And as for wasting time: The moderators are **very busy**; the flag queue is *very* full. Be respectful of their time! We have *far* more reopen queue reviewers. You can easily afford to waste the time of 5 of those.

Comment: Updated the correct duplicate and explanation in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347471/caret-position-in-pixels-in-an-input-type-text-not-a-textarea#comment35819759_13347471), and posted a request on Chat.SO.

Comment: Bottom line - a day later, this still isn't solved.

Answer (score 14):

Your flag points out a flaw in the current flag handling system.

One of the best things that's happened recently to the moderator flag queue was the moving of close vote flags to the close vote queue. Close vote flags were always the hardest for us to handle, since they often required domain-specific expertise to determine if a question should indeed be closed.

The worst of those by far were duplicate votes, since unless something was a word-for-word duplicate they often required you to know the subject matter at hand to be able to properly close them. People often got these completely wrong, and when we went along with it good questions were closed improperly as duplicates. That made a lot of people rather angry, so we became hesitant to act on them. Now that those are in the review queue, community members can vote on them and they can get exposed to people with the right expertise. As a result, we're now declining most of the "other" flags that ask us to close things as duplicates in order to direct them to standard duplicate close votes or close flags.

However, this presents a problem when it comes to people who flag that something was improperly closed as a duplicate of another post. That has the same problems as the duplicate close flags we saw before, only now people are asking us to override the votes of five community members as well. In your case, you're also asking us to re-close it as a duplicate of the third question, which requires us to read and analyze three questions to determine if you're making the right call here. Again, if we get this wrong, we risk not just directing people in the wrong way, but also angering the five close voters.

I'm not quite sure how to handle flags like this if none of us is sure of the assertion that something is not closed correctly as a duplicate. Even if these were kicked into the reopen queue, many of the "not a duplicate" flags we get convey additional information that tries to make a case for why it's not a duplicate. That information would not be presented to reviewers.

The best I can think of is to present your case for why something isn't a duplicate on Meta or in an appropriate chat room. As I said, we're a little leery of handling these if we don't understand the material well enough to see why five voters were wrong in choosing a particular duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I've raised the problem ~9 hours ago on chat but haven't received any interest. One logical solution would be to contact the five closers; however, SO is keen on not offering a way to contact users.

Comment: The point was made [today](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272278/2359271) that the dupehammer makes handling this by community action much simpler (at least, given the presence of a reasonably popular tag).