# How can I find out who declined my flag?

Tags: support, declined-flags, moderators

[This flag I raised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252844/incorrect-wrong-duplicate-question) was incorrectly declined. I would like to politely ask the moderator(s) to reconsider.

How can I find out who declined a flag I raised?

Comment: You cannot. You can ask about specific flags on your site Meta and see if a moderator explains, but there is no way *from the UI* for you to see who declined the flag.

Comment: You can't. You can either raise another flag, post here on Meta, or email the team if it's happening more than once for same post.

Comment: Besides, you can *vote to reopen* yourself; make your case in the comments, organise a team in a chat room perhaps, and then *close* it again, all without moderator intervention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Tried that about ~9 hours ago, and didn't receive any interest on chat. One logical solution would be to contact the five closers; however, SO is keen on not offering a way to contact users.

Comment: @ChrisF (I presume you migrated the question from MSE to MSO). This is a general question about StackExchange. The example I gave happened to be on SO, but I feel the question applies to all SE sites - how can one find out who declined their flag?

Comment: @DanDascalescu: I maintain that your comment is not clear; you do need to pre-chew the whole issue, and why people should actually care.

Answer (score 4):

Moderators are not expected to be arbiters of technical accuracy. This means they do not have to judge the correctness of posts flagged as incorrect or even if the correct duplicate has been chosen.

**This means your flag was not incorrectly declined.**

Of course this doesn't mean that a moderator *won't* take the time to have a look and make a judgment call, it just means you should never expect them to and shouldn't be surprised if your flag is declined.

Possibly a better solution for your problem is to make a feature request - the facility for suggesting a better/more appropriate/additional  duplicate once a question has already been closed as a dupe.

Comment: In addition, it would be great to also handle [cases like this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293892/1064325).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "How can I find out who declined my flag?"

Comment: @augurar You don't need to know who declined your flag. And the question was answered in the comments. I am simply pointing out to the OP that their conclusion and approach is wrong. This answer is almost 7 years old - instead of leaving an unhelpful and pedantic comment, think about improving the answer (that is the more accepted and encouraged Stack Overflow way).

Comment: Part of the idea of Stack Exchange sites is that questions/answers exist in perpetuity for future readers.  That's how I came across this question, because I was looking for the same information.  In my opinion the best way to improve this answer would be to delete it, given that it doesn't answer the question and merely expresses your opinion that the OP's approach is wrong.

Comment: @augurar It's fine for you to disagree with my answer, in which case you should down vote it. But I need to throw in a disclaimer: I am a moderator on one of the SE sites, I was a mod when that answer was written, so "my opinion" is relatively qualified in that respect. I've reviewed my answer to see if it is still correct and/or relevant and I believe it is (I have deleted answers in the past that have become obsolete).

Comment: @augurar Just to follow on.... this is an old question and answer. There is now a UI which shows us the flag history on a post, so we can see historically who raised a flag and which mod dealt with it. But there is no flag review process. This is a subject that has been well discussed over the years, generally if you believe your flag was incorrectly handled you simply question it on meta (should be reserved for decisions that are worth debating) or to simply flag again. There are far too many flags on some sites to introduce a formalised flag review system.