# Headless duplicate question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

This question is marked as a duplicate:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725770/should-the-java-this-keyword-be-used-when-it-is-optional

However, unlike other questions, it doesn't have a link to the question it's a duplicate of.

[image: Question without link to duplicate]

Why is that? Normal duplicates look like this:

[image: Question with link to duplicate]

Has the parent question been deleted or something? If so, why is this one still marked as a duplicate?

Comment: That's not a bug, just a window to when duplicate-closure worked different, the targets are in the comments. Nothing to see here.

Comment: Wow that's an appropriate username :P. But what's the point of marking a question as a duplicate if you can't go to the parent question?

Comment: Weird. Once upon a time the dup links were inserted directly into the question body and could be edited out. Should have happened here but hasn't apparently. Probably leftovers from an age-old bug.

Answer (score 41):

That's not a bug.

In the beginning, when people voted to close as duplicate, they were not prompted for a target.
It was assumed it was already mentioned in the comments (as is the case here, see the last two comments).

Then people started to edit them into the question, in a stylish comment-section at the top.

After that, SE started to prompt for the duplicate and edit it in automatically.

And nowadays, they aren't edited in at all, and the auto-comment added when voting/flagging as duplicate is automatically removed on closing.
Instead, we now have a notice which isn't actually part of the post.

When SE transitioned to the final stage, where possible old posts were auto-converted to the new duplicate-closure method. But yes, that obviously could not catch all instances.

For some more history: [Why was the closing of this question so unusual?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281615/why-was-the-closing-of-this-question-so-unusual)

Comment: I wasn't there back then, but your explanation doesn't explain why the close notice in the edit history lists the three dup targets.

Comment: Well, maybe it automatically picked up all candidate links in comments at closure time. And while in this case, they were all proposed as duplicates, that's not always the case, so it deferrs to the comments for public display, instead of asserting anything. Not sure about that one. Maybe it was yet another transitional stage...

Comment: Can we manually set a question as the one it's a duplicate of?

Comment: Only by re-opening and re-closing. But why bother, they are all there? Anyway, nowadays that question would have been closed as primarily opinion-based, and the answers show why.

Comment: You can see both banners in action [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14244775/1048572) - I changed the old-ish dupe target, but didn't revert the community edit.

Comment: @Deduplicator, you've been a member for less than 2 years, how do you know that? :O

Comment: @TheChamp: Search-fu and reading some of the more interesting meta-posts, on MSO as well as MSE...

Comment: @Deduplicator seems legit. ^^