# Please review the duplicate target for this SQL question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3003457/2359271) is a duplicate – no argument on that count (ha, ha) – but not of [the question that it was closed as a duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1221559/2359271).

Even if you know nothing about SQL, compare the [answer to the closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003533/2359271) to the [answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221649/2359271) - one says "these are different, and here's how" while the other says "there's no difference, and here's why." (Amusingly, both answers were given by the same user.)

I initially raised a custom flag to explain this:

> This seems to have been marked as a dupe of the wrong question. The
>   correct dupe is stackoverflow.com/q/59294/2359271; the linked dupe
>   talks about () vs (1) rather than () vs (column) which is a different
>   question and has a different answer. – AirThomas Aug 20 at 16:34

I noticed today that the flag has been declined. (The reason left was "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it," which is a bit annoying – but no harm, no foul.)

After more research I found Brad Larson's answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252976/2359271) explaining why it's more appropriate for the community to handle these circumstances by voting to re-open the question and then close it with the proper duplicate target. I agree with [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct#comment7538245_3003457) that this proper target is:

[In SQL, what's the difference between count(column) and count(*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count)

3k rep users: Please review the question and cast your votes, if you agree, to reopen and reclose the question with the proper duplicate target.

Comment: Man, I love that gold badge holders can just fix this stuff now... For everyone else: don't forget that you can always edit in links to related posts. It's not *quite* the same as dup-closing, but it's pretty close.

Comment: I've closed [`COUNT(*)` vs `COUNT(1)` vs `COUNT(pk)` — which is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better/2710659?noredirect=1) as a duplicate of [`COUNT(*)` vs `COUNT(1)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1), primarily based on the date asked (2010 for the 3-way question versus 2009 for the 2-way question).  However, there might also be a case for designating the duplicates the other way around as the later question covers the earlier question in its entirety.  Should the closure be reversed?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Worth noting that the former question is vendor-independent, while the latter is asking specifically about SQL Server, so they could potentially diverge in the future. That said, IMO the former should stay closed regardless; "Which is better?" questions are fluff and the CW answer is a mess.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I agree with you that the question you identified is a better fit than the original duplicate target so used my Mjölnir powers to make it so.

Having to drum up 5 reopen votes and then 5 close votes to achieve this all sounds a tremendous waste of time.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a SQLer.

Comment: That THOR attitude can be sooo sexy, I love it! (no offence, I just meant that; and completely OT of course)