# What should I do if suspect the chosen duplicate post is not correct

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I have notice a duplicate post few days ago, which is [How to calculate UNIX timestamp difference using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530413/how-to-calculate-unix-timestamp-difference-using-python)

Indeed, it is already marked as a duplicate by someone, but it is not actually one.

Let's say in the example provided, the problem is actually caused by the fact that `datetime` cannot correctly handle `'PDT'` in string. For the solution of referred post, OP cannot solve his problem.

However, it is still a duplicate as this question is already answered here, [python time string does not match format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704826/python-time-string-does-not-match-format).

I therefore flag the post again to **'make moderators aware'**, but I get

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I understand I am handling this problem wrong, but how should I tell others that they should refer to another post instead of the marked one. Simply by comment?

---

I read this question,
[Incorrect/wrong duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252844/incorrect-wrong-duplicate-question?rq=1) , but unfortunately it just tells how to deal with a suspected duplicate, while I want there to be one more duplicate added (or replace the original one).

Comment: If it's closed by a single user, you can ping the closer with `@username`, and explain in what way they are different. He then can reopen with a single vote if he agrees.

Comment: @user000001 , I will try. But if no response get, can I have for example an option flag to let others (or community) to change it (if consensus)?

Comment: Then, since you don't have 3K rep to cast a reopen vote, your options are quite limited. I raised this issue back in the days of MSE ([Can we have the ability to flag for reopening?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186722)), and the response was that you should edit the question to put it in the reopen queue, or raise the issue on meta.

Comment: For questions like this, you can try the subject chatroom ([Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) for Python). In that room there are often multiple gold-badge users, that can edit the duplicate list without closing and reopening, and most people there are both experienced on SO and Python.

Comment: Stephen edited the duplicate list 4 hours ago.  It is not obvious where the other 4 votes came from, low-rep users perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought that gold badge holders could edit duplicate lists directly.

Comment: What Erik said. In the Python room we're always interested to hear about good dupe targets, whether they're improved or additional targets for closed questions, or proposed targets for dupes that aren't yet closed. The room is fairly active, although it can get quiet during the off-peak hours.

Comment: Add a comment to the question to let people know you think it's not a dupe, and edit the question to clarify it. Users working the reopen queue will see that and should take notice.