# How to update a close vote

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I try to give accurate reasons when voting to close (e.g. to make it easier to deal with my votes in a review queue).

Often I see bad questions that do not include (sufficient) code to be understandable. I then typically vote to close because of *insufficient information*. Sometimes OP comes back and updates his code so my original close reason doesn't make sense anymore, but the question should probably still be closed (e.g. because the problem was a simple typo).

I think this is completely unrelated to updating good questions with more accurate information, e.g. [when closing dups](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252403/i-voted-to-close-with-the-wrong-duplicate-what-should-i-do)

What's the most efficient approach to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

The system does not allow you to change your vote, short of retracting it. And when it is retracted, you can't vote again.

So I'd put in a comment that thanks the OP for the edit that fixed one problem but point out that there are other reasons to close the question. This is especially useful for questions that *could* be fixed. This is often what I do if I notice that a question was edited but that the question is still worthy of being closed.

This can also help in the review queue. Not everybody is equally sensitive to the various close reasons. A reviewer that does not have much experience may not realize that although the original reason you used no longer applies, there's still another reason to close the question.

It is also possible to do nothing at all, and sometimes this is what I do. I realize this does not help the OP of the *specific* question I voted to close if ultimately they get a notice that their question has been closed for a reason they thought they took care of. However, the time I can devote to SO is limited. So the time I spend helping *one* person is time I'm not spending helping *someone else*. Chances are that there's someone who posted something better than the question I've voted to close.

I'm not sure which of these two is the most efficient. I'm quite sure that some of my comments (most, perhaps?) do not have the desired effect of making the OP see the problem.

Comment: I find that approach not very satisfactory. I often filter by close reason when working a queue and having a matching close reason often makes forming a decision much easier (at least for me). Also, given that close votes age I think fast turnaround on closing is crucial for it to work on the scale SO is operating on these days.