# Why can't we vote to close a question after the original vote was retracted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

What is the reason for being able to close a question only once? What I mean is that you can't cast a vote again after you retracted your close vote.

My guess is that this should prevent some abusive behavior. However, being able to close-vote a question multiple times, for different reasons, would be really handy.

**Scenario:**

A user posts a question, and it's not clear what the problem is about. So I vote to close the question as being unclear. Then the OP clarifies the problem and it turns out it's actually a duplicate of an existing question. But now I can't vote to close as a duplicate anymore.

I know I can always comment on the question and state my opinion. However, it feels less efficient/effective if I now have to wait until others are voting to close the question as duplicate. In the worst case, the question doesn't even get closed.

Given our new closing superpowers, this seems to be very limiting. <del>Can't we have something like we can only vote to close a question once per reason?</del>

**Update:**

As far as I see, there are two kinds of close vote reason categories:

- Reasons that **require the OP to take further actions**, i.e. update their question. Specifically, these are

  - unclear what you're asking
  - it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.
- Reasons that **close a question for good**. All the others, but especially:

  - a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error
  - duplicate

After the OP takes action and updates their question, we are basically presented with a new question (or at least a slightly different one), which still might have to be closed, but now for another reason. Maybe we can loosen the "closing only once" restrictions somehow, based on these two categories.

<sub>This probably has been discussed before, but I couldn't find it.</sub>

Comment: Well then people who are just snotty and don't like a question will just use another reason because "the question should still be closed but I can't choose that reason." I wouldn't mind making an exception for duplicates only, since that close reason requires the user to actually select another question.

Comment: I'd assume that a certain level of engagement with the site would indicate that we are mature enough to do such things. But I understand your point and your idea makes sense as well. Let me update my question.

Comment: Unclear to me: "*What I mean is that you **can** cast a vote again after you retracted your close vote.*", => "can" or "can't"...? // + Typo/Grammar Error in "*Users posts*", you don't combine Plural with Singular in a same sentence, it doesn't make sense grammatically... (=> Should be "User posts", I think, from *the rest* of the paragraph...)

Comment: Users can revise the content of their post, but voters can't revise the reason the post should be closed. This is a disparity that does not make sense.

Comment: @chivracq: The last part has now been taken care of.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, yep very good, Thanks, I still find the *first part*, not *resolved*..., "*you can cast a vote again*" , I think they mean the Opposite => "You can't"... Acceptable (= clear!) for me would have been stg like: "*What I mean is that **I wish** you **could** cast a vote again after you retracted your close vote.*" (But the current form is completely unclear, rather strange that this Thread has been "running" for 8 years already, collecting Upvotes, and nbd payed attention at the Wording...)

Answer (score 23):

What if we could vote to change the close reason, without having to reopen and reclose to do so? Possibly *only* changing it to "dup", or changing it from one dup to another.

I realize this has already been brought up:

- [Why can't we change our close vote reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262657/why-cant-we-change-our-close-vote-reason?)
- [Should we allow voting to change the close vote reason of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262761/should-we-allow-voting-to-change-the-close-vote-reason-of-a-question)
- [How to update a close vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253426/how-to-update-a-close-vote)

But I think the restriction to only changing to "dup" makes it different.

When a question has been closed as "needs an MCVE" and the OP comes back with enough information to understand the question, it often becomes apparent that the question is a dup. I can't vote to close it as a dup, because it's already closed. I can vote to reopen it, and leave a comment suggesting that someone else vote to close it as a dup, but that rarely works out well.

Similarly: As a high-rep user, I close a question as a dup. A few hours later, an intermediate-rep user finds a much better dup and mentions it in the comments. I can't change the dup target. I don't want to waste a mod's time. I don't want to leave it closed on a halfway-decent dup when the really good dup can only be found through comments. If I reopen it so the other user can re-close it as a dup, while it's waiting around for 4 more votes, it's going to gather 3 useless answers, one of them voted up to +9 and accepted by people who don't notice that it's just copied and pasted from an answer on the dup.

And so on. There's really no good solution to these problems with the current system. But if we could just vote to change the close reason (and, obviously, allow people who'd voted to close to do so), it would solve these problems, and I don't see any way that could be abused for open/close wars.

---

The obvious argument against this is [the one Robert Harvey gave](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262788/908494) to the second question above: "The close reason doesn't really matter enough to fix". But that answer only got half as many votes as [Trilarion's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262842/908494) "The close reasons matter or we needn't bother with them at all. They give guidance to the questioners as well as to the close voters.".

Comment: Given that you reference *two* of my questions, I obviously agree.  I think most importantly, it can be confusing for a new user when the close reason is wrong (or the dup-target is sub-optimal).  I somewhat regularly see MSO questions that probably could be prevented if the close reason were changed from the original reason to the more accurate reason after the edit.

Comment: @nhgrif: Do you think I need to make that more prominent in the answer? I thought it was more important to cover how this discussion is different from the previous ones, and just highlight the reason this keeps coming up with the quote from Trilarion at the end… but you're right, that's pretty important, and maybe it needs more focus.

Comment: I agree as well. It is exactly like you said: Often the question is unclear at the beginning and after it was clarified, it's a duplicate. If I already have a pretty good idea what the duplicate could be, I'm waiting to close the question as "unclear". But that doesn't sound like the desired process either...

Comment: I just voted to close a question as a duplicate but I picked the wrong duplicate... retracted, then could not reclose.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ScottBeeson This problem has been (partially) solved since 2015. On a question closed as a dup, gold-badge users (I think, although maybe it's rep instead?) can edit the dup target, or even add multiple dup targets. If you don't have the rep to do that, you can at least leave a comment suggesting a better dup. Hopefully, then, someone will come along and edit the dup target. If the question is on a popular tag that has a chat room associated with it, you can probably recruit someone there to do the edit. If worst comes to worst, at least the comment is helpful.

Comment: Why only dup? "was caused by a typo [...]" comes up very often too with question edited multiple times.

Answer (score 21):

You get one close vote on a question to reduce the possibility of open/close wars.  If the question is to be closed again, it must be closed by a different group of people than the ones who originally closed it.

There are no close reasons that close a question for good.  All closures are subject to reopening if they can attract the requisite number of votes.

The same applies for duplicates; you only get one bite at the apple.  If you get it wrong, someone else has to close on the correct duplicate.

Comment: I just voted to close a question as a duplicate but I picked the wrong duplicate... retracted, then could not reclose.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @THEJOATMON Same here.

Comment: This doesn't explain why you can't vote to close again after retracting the close vote.

Answer (score 8):

If you were allowed **to change your close reason exactly once** per question, that would ease your workflow a lot.

If questions lack details and clarity (which happens a lot), I post my suggestions for improvement as comments. Then I'm never sure, if I should either immediately vote to close and forfeit the possibility to use the appropriate close reason once there's an actual question or wait for a day and close then. The latter is incredibly impractical, though.

I'd also like to remind you all that there are several combinations of close reasons that can warrant changing from one to the other after an edit. Typical examples include:

- Duplicate -> Other duplicate
- Needs debugging details -> Duplicate
- Needs debugging details -> Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
- Not written in English -> Any other close reason
- Needs details or clarity -> Duplicate
- Needs details or clarity -> Needs debugging details
- Needs details or clarity -> Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
- Needs more focus -> Duplicate
- Needs more focus -> Needs debugging details
- Needs more focus -> Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
- Needs more focus -> Needs details or clarity

Using the compromise of allowing two close votes (not at the same time) would ease our workflow a lot, while still keeping the process relatively simple. If you inspect the list above closely (e.g. first attempt was in Spanish), you'll see that in some cases, one might still want to change the close reason more often but I think it's okay if that possibility isn't there.

Having an effective way to change close votes (and I think allowing two is the way) has two significant advantages:

- Questions that deserve it are closed faster, freeing volunteer time to answer good questions.
- It's more likely that the appropriate close reason will be displayed at the top of the question once it's closed. This is especially important for duplicates.

### There's a feature request on the Stack Exchange Meta

It might be useful to continue this discussion on the corresponding meta.stackexchange.com [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction) because this issue is not specific to Stack Overflow.