# Why can't we change our close-vote reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, close-reasons

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254781/2792531)  does a fair enough job explaining why you can't vote-to-close on a question once you've retracted a close vote.  But I'm curious, why can't I change my close-vote reason without retracting my close vote?

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582038/restarting-game-with-a-button) started as a question that was too broad.  There wasn't enough detail in the question to do anything more than guess at the appropriate answer.  I downvoted, voted-to-close, and then left a comment explaining why the question needs improvement.

It was then edited in response to my comment to include more detail making it more clear what was being asked about, but it was my feeling that the question still needed to be close, but now for a different reason: it's now a duplicate.

As of this writing, it's 1 close vote away from being closed.  It'll likely be closed, but the question already have 3 close votes before it was clear that the question was a duplicate, so when the question is closed, the official close reason is unlikely to be because it's a duplicate.

Why is my only option to retract my close vote?  Why do I not have an option to change my close vote reason now that the question has been edited from one closable problem to another?

Comment: Sometimes I close a question by mistake and than I've to do nothing but retract my vote, it would be nice if they provided to change the close vote reason, atlease once should be allowed

Comment: maybe be a bit less trigger happy on the close vote to begin with.

Comment: @tcaswell That's not particularly helpful.  You're basically arguing that I shouldn't ever vote to close because it's possible that the question will later be edited into something that invalidates my close vote (but leaves the question in a state that should still be closed).  Even after the edit from "unclear" to "duplicate", it's possible the user could edit again out of "duplicate" but into "too broad" or some other category.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262761/should-we-allow-voting-to-change-the-close-vote-reason-of-a-question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't we vote to close a question after the original vote was retracted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254778/why-cant-we-vote-to-close-a-question-after-the-original-vote-was-retracted)

Comment: @GolezTrol Not a duplicate at all.  In fact, I point to that and directly explain how and why this question is different.

Comment: Just hit this myself - question as phrased was a duplicate (so I voted as such), but later on more information came to light where it was clearly off topic due to typographical error.  Ended up just retracting my vote.

Comment: This happens quite often, a pity nothing was done about it. Should be worth bumping.

Comment: It would be really nice to stop bikeshedding over this and just get it done. It shouldn't be a lot of work, and it's not an edge case. Just today I closed a JavaScript question as a typo (the OP used `obj.field` instead of `obj[field]`), then realized that actually it should be closed as a dup of the canonical question about property access. I couldn't change my close reason, so I was reduced to leaving a comment pointing to the dup, which left the question open to more stupid answers before someone else came along to hammer it.

Comment: @torazaburo agreed. Not to mention that when you have the gold badge converting to duplicate closes the question. Retracting close vote/not being able to convert close vote reason condemns you to watch the stupid/generic answers pouring down. That sometimes refrains me from voting python questions as "too broad" or "unclear" until I can find a canonical dupe.

Comment: Still a problem 3 years later. Yesterday I voted to close a question as "unclear what you are asking". Today OP clarified adequately, but in a way that makes it much too broad. I'll probably just retract the close-vote as the lesser of 2 evils.

Comment: Still a problem **5** years later, and neither an actual answer nor a real workaround has been offered. :(

Comment: Still a problem **6** years later.

Comment: Still a problem **8** years later, and has not been answered or solved. Today I voted to close a question for lack of clarity, later to find it has been previously asked by the same person, so it's actually a duplicate, and I had to put that in a comment.

Comment: Yep, still a problem 8 years later.  You vote to close a question as "unclear, needs details".  They provide the details and now it's a clear duplicate.  Can't do anything about that.  with  the system as it is, it removes reasons for voting to close "needs details" because sometimes when the details are provided, it  needs to be closed for a different reason and you can't do anything about that.

Comment: Overwhelmingly supported by the meta community, status-declined with no explanation... why am I not surprised?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it was partially applied, in a way that solved the problem for the majority of cases. There *is* in fact an explanation of why it wasn't implemented fully in the answers below.

Comment: I disagree that editing duplicate reasons is anywhere near "the majority of cases", and the explanation seems really suspect to me - why wouldn't it work to just check if the user has cast and retracted a close vote previously, and re-apply the old timestamp?

Comment: the explanation being suspect, is vastly different from *"status-declined with no explanation"*

Answer (score 35):

Especially for gold tag badge owners, it's really a pity that it's not implemented, mostly because sometimes you close as "too broad" when you could have dupehammered.

So there's a perverse effect for those gold tag badge owners. Me, I tend to wait until it's clear that it's a duplicate, and not vote to close in the meanwhile (which would have been the thing to do).

However, on the bright side:

- if you close-voted as a duplicate and it's not the right one, as a gold tag badge owner, you can change the duplicate: [What should I do as a gold badge holder if I feel the duplicate target isn't the right one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355666/what-should-i-do-as-a-gold-badge-holder-if-i-feel-the-duplicate-target-isnt-the)
- the above applies if you can find an existing Q&A that answers the particular question (in case of a well-known typo/beginner mistake). I suggest you collect those links and use them. It's not abuse to close a question as a duplicate ... that is also off-topic because of a typo ;) ([several examples in a previous answer of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356359/6451573))
- if you feel that the question isn't getting enough close votes quickly enough, and low quality answers are pouring in in the meantime, why not summon [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)? Helpful users will nail the coffin for you, which can go as far as downvoting+deleting the Q&A altogether. There are even nice integrated [scripts](https://socvr.org/tools/userscripts) running with Tampermonkey to help you do that with a few clicks.

Comment: I'm here because I voted to close a question because it wasn't clear what the author of the question was asking for, once clarified I wanted to change my vote to it being a duplicate, but cannot.

Comment: What about the case where a question initially "needs details or clarity", and then the details or clarity make it evident that i) the question is a duplicate, or ii) OP had a typo?

Comment: "needs details" when it's a typo isn't really a big deal. And in the case it's a duplicate, I'm answering already "  tend to wait until it's clear that it's a duplicate, and not voting to close in the meanwhile (which would have been the thing to do).". Well of course now I can change close vote reason whenever I choose...

Comment: It's even worse than I thought for gold-badge owners. If I mark something that should be closed for a non-duplicate reason (for example as a typo), and then *another* gold-badge user comes along and makes a bad selection of dupe-hammer and I undo that, *my close vote is lost and I can't redo it*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel true but you can edit the duplicate target to find a typo Q&A that has already been answered to try to improve the target... then also use roomba forceaster and vote to delete if you can to clean up the site.

Comment: What on Earth is "roomba forceaster"? And hold on, there are "typo Q&A"s? Despite problems caused by typos being off-topic?

Comment: roomba forecaster is a tampermonkey script that tells you (and can remind you) when you can vote to delete. About typo Q&A, there are well known Q&A (also highly upvoted in the 20th century...) that answer to classical typos. I suggest you collect those links and use them. It's not abuse to close a question by a duplicate ... that is also off topic because of a typo ;)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel there are lots of typo Q&As despite them being off-topic exactly for the reason that users who see the question can't re-cast or change close-votes after the question is edited.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel AFAIK, common typos are on-topic, though (e.g. forgetting an underscore in a Python name). The relevant test is whether someone else is likely to encounter the same problem.

Comment: @Joooeey right; I've evolved quite at bit as a curator since then.

Answer (score -11):

The given close reason now is wrong. If we would be going according to the book it would have to be reopened and then closed (according to the linked Answer to another question) by other people because everyone only has one close reason per question.

However questions rarely get reopened from my experience when they are improved after being on hold. So if this question should be closed then not doing anything will result practically in the desired state, however with the wrong reason.

A comment is been given indicating the possible duplicate and sending the questioner to a working solution, which is really good.

A moderator could maybe still change the close reason to make it more clear why this question needs to be closed.

If you could change your closing reason it could indeed be seen as casting two votes (first vote for reason A, then question gets reopened, then you change your vote to reason B and thereby take part in closing it again). Not sure about the open/close wars as mentioned in the linked answer (I only see close wars currently) so it might be nice to have this feature (change close reason as long as question is not fully closed yet) but it also might be possible to just tell moderators about it so they can fix these cases.

Comment: "If you could change your closing reason it would be indeed like casting two votes" - why would it? It's about *changing* the reason, not *adding* another one.

Comment: _"Questions rarely get reopened from my experience when they are improved after being on hold."_ This is inaccurate, those who spend time in the reopen queue know that questions remain closed because they remain flawed.  The rate of successful reopen attempts is indeed low, but reopening does happen when justified.

Comment: @BartoszKP You vote for one reason, the question is edited, you vote a second time for another reason or you change your first reason - there is no difference between changing the reason of the first vote or voting a second time. At least you could see it this way. Changed the answer.

Comment: @BradKoch I cannot yet spent my time in the reopen queue but my own experience where I tried to improve questions that were on hold but never ever got reopened seems to indicate that it is not true that questions remain closed because they remain flawed. So I beg to differ.

Comment: @Trilarion I still don't get it. In what ways there is no difference? If there were 3 close votes, including yours, then the question is edited and you change your close vote reason there would be still 3 close votes. If you're referring to the comments that are automatically added with a CV, there are many obvious possible ways to handle this also.

Comment: @BartoszKP I don't mean two votes in the sense that the weight is doubled but two votes in the sense that you can take part two times in a closing. As it is the question was closed for the wrong reason. It should be reopened and closed for the right reason. As Robert Harvey in the linked answer points out the second closure should be accomplished by different people. If you could change your vote reason you would take part in the second closure round (as I see it) and therefore violate the stated principle that everyone should only vote once per question. See updated answer for a compromise.

Comment: @BaroszKP As you can see I'm not really against changing the close vote reason. I wonder myself what these open/close wars might be.

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks for explaining, now I get it.

Comment: Robert Harvey's got an answer in the related question as well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262761/should-we-allow-voting-to-change-the-close-vote-reason-of-a-question

Comment: @nhgrif Thanks for linking. Although I don't agree with him. Will comment there. If the close reason doesn't really matter, we don't need to bother with it all all.

Answer (score -16):

Because the simplest implementation for this would be to allow you to retract and then re-apply your close vote.

And allowing *that* would allow you to circumvent [the close vote aging mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away/166124#166124), the close review system, and probably other things that assume one vote per person per post.

The other way to implement this would be a new tool that lets you "edit your vote" in place without actually creating a *new* vote. That's probably feasible, but a lot of work for an edge-case.

Given the common need for this involves duplicates, it probably makes more sense to design a system that allows adding / editing duplicate links without the overhead of the rest of the close system. Such functionality could also be useful in cases where the question was *already* closed, where a better duplicate was identified later on, etc. **March 3rd, 2017:** [this duplicate list edit feature is now implemented.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)

Comment: "Editing" your vote is a lot closer to what I'm talking about.  And I'm only talking about cases in which the post has been edited since your close vote casting.  If the user saw 3 close votes and read comments explaining the close votes, so he deleted his post and posted a new question which resolved that close problem but created another, I'd be able to "re-vote" on the new one for a new reason, right?  How is this drastically different from the user completely rewriting the existing question and me changing my close vote reason?

Comment: It's not an edge case, IMO.

Comment: I agree with @RobertCrovella that this isn't an edge case.  I find myself w̶a̶n̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ needing to do it multiple times per day.

Comment: What about allowing the voter to change their close reason only after the OP has edited the question? This would cover the most common cause of complaint, where the OP edits their vague question into a duplicate.

Comment: Seems like a way to prevent the user from circumventing the close vote aging mechanism would be to lock a close vote reason unless the question is edited, similar to how standard voting is handled.

Comment: I can see how people would see this as not being an edge case: if I vote to close a question as Unclear, which is then edited to be Too Broad, then the existing close reason would be invalidated, and the question would either be reopened (and still too broad), or left closed with an overly confusing reason. It does happen, and (in my experience) more often than not the question is just left closed with an overly confusing reason. This doesn't matter usually because the roomba script will remove the question automatically eventually, but sometimes the question doesn't meet the criteria.

Comment: So the real problem as you mention in [your answer to another similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262920/4639281), is the deletion of the content. I think that a solution making it easier to delete bad content would be an acceptable solution. Maybe not a better solution in a perfect world, but an acceptable solution for the world we live in.

Comment: Is circumventing the vote aging *really* a problem? At worst, you could keep a perpetual 1 close vote against a question, assuming you remember to come back every 100 days and re-apply it. Seems like a lot of effort for effectively no result.

Comment: @Rob ~14 days, not 100

Comment: That's not really the problem, @Rob; the problem is that aging doesn't *start* until at least 4 days after the last close vote. So if you're constantly bouncing your vote, it never starts.

Comment: So, @Tiny... [As you know](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats), maybe 15% of Unclear questions get edited. And I rather doubt that you diligently revisit EVERY question you vote to close until they're deleted. Not that it matters, since what you seem to be asking for now is the ability to change the binding close reason *after* the question is closed, which is an entirely different set of headaches from the one originally proposed here, and which I did address elsewhere already. In summary, earn 10K already.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't actually really proposing anything, just remarking at how others may perceive a problem. And yes, I'm well aware of those stats. We do have a bot in the SOCVR that monitors the questions that get close requests (and are closed by us), and notifies us when there are edits. The problem with that is that everything the bot has shown us so far (even up to a 100% levenshtein distance from the original post) is not worth reopening. So yeah, I agree that it most definitely isn't a problem worth solving, which is why I would hop on the deletion band-wagon. (cont'd)

Comment: So if you want my throw-away proposal, here it is: Give the 20k deletion privileges to the 10k-ers.

Comment: If you have a bot tracking these then you've already solved the biggest deficiency in 10K delete privileges, @Tiny. You just need, y'know, that privilege.

Comment: Yeah, as soon as that 1.8k bounty comes along.

Comment: @Shog9 Right, that makes more sense then

Comment: Define "a lot of work".

Comment: there's no way to "retract and then re-apply" for the new vote. Once I retract my vote I can no longer vote on that question

Comment: Actually, that edit regarding "this is now implemented" didn't really implement what was mentioned in the answer. It allows gold tag badge holders to edit the list of duplicates when it's already been closed, whereas the answer details editing your own close *vote*, with no reference to tag badges.

Comment: The "circumventing the vote aging" problem is only a flimsy excuse. The edited close vote could be set as old (w.r.t. the aging) as the original one. This is possible with retracted and recast votes, too.

Comment: I believe there is some sort of time period you need to wait after retracting your close vote before you can add another

Comment: Whatever you implemented for duplicate votes doesn't work very well. If I undo *someone else's* dupe-hammering, my original close vote is *lost and cannot be redone*. What was that about "circumventing vote aging"?

Comment: I think it would be *much* simpler to just let a user change their vote type while keeping the `datetime` for when it was cast the same. If anything, gaming the vote aging system is what seems like the edge case; it's a theoretical issue preventing a solution to a demonstrated, regularly-encountered problem... that's *no bueno*. Add a db column with a binary value to enforce only changing your vote one time to preempt potential abuse.

Comment: Third paragraph, @tyler. Best solution, but not simple. Editing without audit trail is a bad idea, would want some sort of history.

Comment: @Shog9 OK, two (or three) extra columns. One for have they changed their vote, one for when they changed their vote, and an optional 3rd for what their original vote was. I know editing db tables isn't always super easy, but if one bothers to go through adding a column, adding a couple more at the same time should be fairly trivial.

Comment: That limits audits to 1 change; would probably add a new flag type to track changes. But implementation details aside, of course it is possible - question is, is it worthwhile? Obviously lots of folks think it is... I kinda think it would be better if closing was less immutable overall, more like editing. The need to edit edits is exceedingly rare, because usually can correct any issues with another edit.