# Allow change to a close vote after question is edited

Tags: feature-request, edits, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

The issue of changing close votes [has come up before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262657/why-cant-we-change-our-close-vote-reason) quite a few times. I understand the rationale for not generally permitting changing votes. However, there is a specific, **very common** case with a clear algorithm that I believe should be handled:

- Alice votes to close Bob's question (in particular, "specific problem or error", as Bob did not supply the code in question).
- Bob edits his question in response.
- The question now merits a new close reason--in particular, it's now clearly a duplicate.

This is a pattern that shows up three or four times a week *just for me personally*, regarding [my canonical question about unmanaged Spring beans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870/1189885).

In the case where *the original poster has edited a question since a voter cast her close vote*, she should be able to recast the vote. This is **especially** a problem with duplicates, as close-voters don't even have the option available to "flag as duplicate".

Comment: As to your unmanaged spring beans, just shove 'em this way, please, I'll cook 'em up and eat 'em.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315394/1927206

Comment: @BillWoodger I see. While I think the problem as a whole needs to be revisited, I believe my partial solution is both specific and manageable, in contrast to previous posts. (And maybe the negative score is why the other one didn't show up? I searched for various combinations of "close", "edit", and "retract", all of which are in it.)

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with this feature-request. This has happened to me several times also and it's quite frustrating.

Comment: @NathanOliver And just try clicking it after retracting.

Comment: @NathanOliver the point is if you already voted as too broad (no detail)... then OP updates question and it is then a duplicate you can't change to another close reason.  *"Change My Reason"* button would cover that

Comment: +1 When I suspect an unclear question might be a duplicate, I don't want to vote "unclear what you are asking" because if it's clarified later, I won't be able to use my dupehammer.

Comment: Just to add, the example in the question isn't even close to be the only reason. There are so many reasons for wanting to validly change a close vote. A question edit can literally turn any close reason into a completely different reason. Thankfully, and I am not sure if this was always the case, but you can currently change your choice of duplicate, which is at least something

Comment: Totally agree there should be some way to change close votes after the OP has edited their question beside just retracting them. On a number of occasions I've been in situation where the OP has corrected or at least changed their question in response to comments. Sometimes that's fine and I can retract my close votes. However there's been a number of cases where initially the question was initially unclear, but after clarification, something else is then wrong with it—such it's now being too broad. I find SO's current rules pertaining to this arbitrary and frustrating, at best...

Comment: I JUST had the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911867/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-using-babel-loader)

Answer (score 17):

I agree with the particular focus of this proposal, and I'd like to see it get more play as a serious feature request.

This is a *frequent* scenario:

1. OP asks vague question.
2. I vote to close for one of the usual reasons (unclear, no MCVE or other code, etc.).
3. OP edits to supply more info.
4. Aha! So *that's* what the question was! Well, that's a clear duplicate.

But now I can't replace my close vote and mark it as a duplicate. I can't dupehammer it; I can't even register that the question *is* a duplicate, except by a comment (which is what I use).

I believe that users with sufficient rep to dupehammer should have sufficient rep to retract a close-vote and dupehammer, and I specifically propose that feature. Surely it would be easy to implement, and the improvement in site editing would be phenomenal.

Comment: After the question is edited, it goes to the reopen queue, correct? Then it can be reopened, and afterwards closed as a duplicate by other users who see your "This looks like a duplicate" comment.

Comment: [This one was not edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911867/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-using-babel-loader), but still could be dupe-hammered instead of just "not enough information"

Comment: @jkdev often the question is not closed in the first place because the asker is quicker with editing. But I still can't flag as duplicate if I've flagged for something else before.