# Using assumed information in question duplicate closure

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50243504/734069). I'm certain that this is a duplicate of [this canonical question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839586/opengl-object-in-c-raii-class-no-longer-works). The problem is, there's not enough information in the question to truly know that; I'm assuming it based on considerable experience and the properties of what the OP says is happening, not because I can see the actual bug in the code.

Now, I could go and VTC as "lacking MCVE" since it is. But that requires 4 other people. I could ask for an MCVE from the OP, but again this doesn't get anyone to the answer that I *know they want*. What's worse, if I comment to ask for an MCVE *and* vote to close... then I can't dupe-hammer it later, once the OP confirms what I already know to be true.

What is the right way to handle this? My personal instinct is to just dupe-hammer it and move on, since that will simultaneously solve the OPs problem, give us a (marginally) useful title for the canonical dupe in searches, and require the least amount of other users' time.

Comment: If in doubt that it's an exact duplicate, or if the dupe will solve the question, leave it open but leave a comment (great! - that's what you did). Once the question get clarified others can take the necessary action even if you are not around at that time. Unfortunately having the hammer doesn't allow you to vote as dupe and display the auto "Possible duplicate of..." comment (it gets created and deleted immediately), so you'll have to manually paste the link(s) in a comment.

Comment: "there's not enough information in the question to truly know [the answer]" then, vote as unclear. Ask for the missing information. That's it. Work with the information you have on hand, that way mistakes wouldn't be made.

Comment: @Braiam: If I had, the question would still be sitting at 2-3 close votes. By *not* voting to close, when the OP provided sufficient information to "know" the answer, I could dupe-hammer it and end the question entirely, rather than waiting for someone else to arrive.

Comment: Do not forget to accept answer in your cannonical question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could post an answer that details your presumptions and introduces your existing answer as the solution.

If the asker confirms your assumptions, hammer it. If they dispute them without clarifying, close. If they dispute *and* clarify, delete your answer and move on.

Though honestly... I'd probably just hammer it and leave a comment asking the author to post details if it *wasn't* a duplicate. You can always reopen if the question ends up being both novel *and* complete, or edit the duplicate links if it is complete but a duplicate of something else.

Comment: After the edit, this is better.  Hammer it, explain if needed, and move on.  Life is too short to always try and intricately explain your presumptions...  Paint with the broad brush as needed, and go on with life.

Comment: It honestly took me an hour to remember that we added dup link editing. That makes everything much simpler.

Comment: I err on the side of dupehammering for the very reasons mentioned by OP. But if I wrote the dup target, I would just post a "Possible duplicate link" to be [extra careful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367466/9209546).

Comment: @jpp I have similar misgivings about hammering to my own dupes, but I don't let it stop me.

Comment: Just be diligent about reopening when there's good cause. There's a good reason for the privilege to apply to both closing and reopening.