# Can "creative use" of the dupe hammer go too far?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, dupehammer

Look at this creative (mis)use of Mjoelner [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178386/bootstrap-4-navbar-items-on-right-side) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-items-to-the-right). The situation is :

1. A question is answered and accepted Oct 22 '16 at 15:33 by "User Zero" with +100 upvotes. The answer is maintained and up to date.
2. A similar question is posted and answered Jan 6 '17 at 20:25 by "User X". That answer is no different from the "original" answer made by "User Zero" back in '16.
3. Now, Feb 22 '18 at 14:12 "User X" marks the old question as a duplicate of the newer question and by that his own accepted answer. If the dupe hammer should be used here, the question from '17 should be marked as a duplicate of the question from '16. The answer from '17 does not bring any new not already covered by the question from '16 and its accepted answer.
4. "User X" even marks both questions as protected.

In my opinion this behavior is highly unethical and should be banned. It is nothing but *reputation theft*. It is not the purpose of the dupe hammer, it is nothing but **abuse of the privilege**.

How to prevent this kind of behavior? What to to? Please dont tell "*suggest to reopen*" or "*gain 1000 upvotes on the tag so you can reopen*".

I think it is a serious problem - it degrades the entire credibility of stackoverflow and its users.

Personally I take the dupe hammer really serious. I actually avoid to use it if the only answer I can find is one of my own (which actually happens on a certain tag). And certainly I could not dream about browsing around and find old questions with accepted answers, and mark them as "duplicate" to newer completely similar questions and answers.

In my opinion it ruins the whole idea with duplicates and the dupe hammer.

So, what about a rule or mechanism, where people not is allowed to mark older questions with accepted answers as duplicate of newer questions?

And, or, if that is somehow not doable, simply disallow people to mark an older question as duplicate of a newer question *if* they have answered the question themselves?

Comment: I have to agree that the action you have noted does have the *appearance* of being self-serving, even if it wasn't done for this purpose. The dupe-hammer is a very high-powered and heavy-handed tool, and so extra discretion should be employed in its use.

Comment: Also, I have notified Themes.guide of this discussion so that they may contribute to this discussion, and perhaps clarify the motivation behind their recent actions

Comment: I tried to replace a horribly written, completely unorganized, and poorly documented but highly upvoted accidental canonical with a well written and documented alternative. It has been closed as a duplicate of the older crap "canonical" question for 2 years now because of this incessant idea that "The older question must always be the target". That's complete and utter nonsense if you ask me. The better Q&A should be the target, forget the age and votes. Spending 5 minutes writing a crap answer 8 years ago doesn't entitle you to a lifetime of the spotlight on that topic for your answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant, Yes, that *could* be the case, and actually what I have in mind when I suggest that a strict rigid rule like "*an older question cannot be marked as a duplicate of a newer*" not is "doable" (it will actually prevent better quality). But this is not the case here.  A simple google search on "*marked as duplicate by [User X]" site:stackoverflow.com* proves there is a pattern of what I will call misuse of the dupe hammer privilege. I have nothing against "User X" at all, clearly a skilled user that provide good answers - I just think the behavior somehow should be banned / suppressed.

Comment: @Dukeling: "The only potential problem is the bias..." and therein lies the rub

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the perception of bias. Perhaps have a look at my answer and if you think you can improve it, please do so.

Comment: @Dukeling, there is no conflict of interest here. I have the "health" of SO in mind. I have no interest in the bootstrap4 tag and think "User X" is an excellent provider of answers to that tag. I just think the use of the dupe hammer is too "creative" here.  Think about it, what if all did the same? If everybody with DH privilege on a tag marked older, perfectly similar questions as duplicates to new questions they have answered? It would be a race for the "old" garde, it would prevent skilled newcomers to achieve reps and privileges. It would certainly confuse visiters ...

Comment: See my answer to the linked duplicate for my rationale here. Let's handle abuse on a case by case basis.

Comment: @davidkonrad: I want to address this: "*A simple google search on "marked as duplicate by [User X]" site:stackoverflow.com proves there is a pattern of what I will call misuse of the dupe hammer privilege.*" No, there is not. I did exactly that search, and what I found was a user doing their job: dupe-hammering *new questions* as old ones. The fact that the old ones contained answers of his own in several, but not all, cases is irrelevant. You are more likely to know that something is a duplicate if you've answered it before.

Comment: Abuse of dupe-hammering has to be something more than closing new questions as duplicates of questions you posted answers on. What you call "misuse of the dupe hammer privilege" is not.

Comment: "*I actually avoid to use it if the only answer I can find is one of my own*" This means you're leaving a duplicate open which is bad. You're not closing a question to direct potential upvotes to your answer, you're closing a duplicate question for another as it's perfectly valid to do so. The fact your answer is on the dupe is irrelevant in the action of closing a *legitimate* dupe. Your answer deserves upvotes too, as much as if it was someone else's answer. The only thing to avoid is closing as a dupe when there's any grey area in it being a dupe (whether it contains your answer or not).

Answer (score -15, accepted):

As it stands the gold badge holders duplicate vote is binding. This makes it tricky if the target question is better and has an answer that they've posted.

To clear up any perceived conflict of interest or ill-doing, whether or not there has been, it might be possible to limit the dupe hammer powers to target questions the hammer holder has not answered. This would not be too difficult to implement. Making the user's vote only worth one vote in the case there may be a perceived conflict of interest. This then puts the question into the close vote review queue and gives the community the opportunity to decide if the dupe closing and target is indeed the best choice.

Same as with moderation on Stack Overflow. Moderators avoid handling flags on their own posts, or where they may be seen to have a vested interest in the discussion (re comment flags).

This may leave some questions unclosed for longer, but would remove question of foul play dupe hammering. Often the issue is not actual foul play, but the perceived threat of it.

Comment: "*...to limit the dupe hammer powers to target questions the hammer holder has not answered*" - That sounds like an excellent solution to me.

Comment: @davidkonrad yeh, still give them the right to vote, but remove the conflict of interest.  I don't think I've worded my answer very well. If anyone thinks they can improve it, I'm happy for the edits.

Comment: I will suggest "*If the person with dupe hammer privilege try to mark a question as duplicate to another question where he or she own the accepted answer, then the vote for closing as duplicate only count as 1, and there still need another 4 closevotes or another with dupe hammer privileges that point to the same question, to close*"

Comment: @YvetteColomb: "*It might be possible (not too difficult to implement) to limit the dupe hammer powers to target questions the hammer holder has not answered.*" At which point, writing canonical questions stops making sense. A person who is active enough on a tag to know that certain categories of questions are asked frequently enough to need a canonical question are also the people who will need to dupe-hammer them. Stopping them from being able to do so makes it that much harder, particularly on lower-traffic tags, to get questions properly closed.

Comment: @NicolBolas, No one will stop anyone from dupe hammering already answered questions; just those with conflict of interest. Why should anyone dupe hammer an older question with an accepted answer with a newer question, with a similar accepted answer, and it is your own, if it is not about highlighting your own answer and nothing else? There can not be any other reason. If you answer the same, more or less, you should use your dupe hammer privilege to point to the old question, not construct a similar answer and by time mark the old question as a duplicate to the new.

Comment: @davidkonrad: "*Why should anyone dupe hammer an older question with an accepted answer with a newer question, with a similar accepted answer, and it is your own, if it is not about highlighting your own answer and nothing else?*" How do you tell what is a "similar accepted answer" is? You can mechanically determine when a "conflict of interest" might exist, but you cannot determine whether the answers are "similar" enough to qualify. As to the specifics of canonical questions, I'm working on an answer to your question that will cover it.

Comment: @NicolBolas, "*How do you tell what is a "similar accepted answer" is*" -
 because I am a programmer and understand the answers. In the case I have raised as case or example for the general point, a user or googler will end up with the same result: Use `mr-auto`, `ml-left` and so on. The answers point to the exact same knowledge or "way to do"...And there is only those answers, it is not the case that you have multiple valid solutions. Both answers could be marked as duplicates to the other, the righrt thing to do is to mark the new question as duplicate of the older, not the opposit ....

Comment: @davidkonrad: "*because I am a programmer and understand the answers.*" No automated system can do that. So Yvette's suggestion, which is what I was talking about, wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: @NicolBolas, It would be just "easy" to implement the rule. I dont know if you have dupe hammer privileges on any tag, but you suggest a link and that link can be refused if there is no accepted or upvoted answers. It would be easy (I guess, at least compared to all the other fancy stuff on SO) to implement a check to see if you also own the accepted answer on the supposed duplicate you try to link to.

Comment: @NicolBolas It was a suggestion. Either way I'm not fussed. It was a possible answer to the question and written with the specific purpose of finding out if the community would like it or not.

Comment: I think this is a fair answer. Related: [How to use gold dupehammer without abuse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367459/how-to-use-gold-dupehammer-without-abuse). Personally, I think gold dupehammer holders should have *the option* to have a regular, non-binding duplicate vote too.

Comment: @davidkonrad - Why is chronology so important? Often the more recent questions are better because (obviously) they're up-to-date. *"Both answers could be marked as duplicates to the other, the right thing to do is to mark the new question as duplicate of the older, not the opposite"*. I don't agree. If the older question is less relevant, it should be closed. In many cases the older question simply isn't as useful to future readers as the newer question. Why is it better just because it's older?

Answer (score 14):

> How to prevent this kind of behavior? What to to? Please dont tell "suggest to reopen" or "gain 1000 upvotes on the tag so you can reopen".

Um, why not? That's the standard solution when close votes get misused: you vote to reopen the question. Whether it took 1 vote or 5, the remedy is always the same. 5 reopen votes can undo a single dupehammer vote.

> I think it is a serious problem - it degrades the entire credibility of stackoverflow and its users.

I find this to be hyperbole. Even if we accept that this behavior is a problem, that hardly rises it to the level of destroying the site's credibility.

In this case, the user in question did not answer the question and immediately go around to dupe-hammer every possible question as a duplicate of that one. It was over a *year* before they hammered the older question.

Closing one of the questions as a duplicate of the other is the correct move. Which one gets closed is not nearly as important as having one of them closed. That's not to say that the OP made the right decision. But I don't get the sense that the decision to close-vote was the craven, self-serving choice you make it out to be. It seems much more likely the user ran into the old question, remembered that they had answered it before, and closed it as a duplicate of their question.

Especially since, by that point, the OP had gotten most of the rep they're going to get from that answer. So this doesn't really look like gaming the system or something.

The other thing you forget is that the initial failure in the system was that a duplicate question was asked and it took over a year before *someone* noticed. Both questions were heavily viewed, so it's not like nobody saw either of them.

Solving that problem is far more likely to pay off in the long run than the one you cite here.

---

A big problem with providing any kind of restriction on dupe-hammering for questions that have that person's answers on them is that it reduces the utility of writing canonical questions.

A canonical question is a semi-broad question that exists primarily to be the destination of a lot of dupe votes. Such questions are usually explicitly written for this purpose, so they tend to be worded in a very general way.

Allow me to provide an example: [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices)

See, the multiple index rendering question comes up in a lot of specific ways. There are several popular mesh file formats that use multiple indices. Rendering cubes (an unfortunately popular past-time for newbies thanks to Minecraft) is another common circumstance. And there are others.

This question skips all of those specifics and focuses on the need for indexing different vertex attributes with different indices. That's the point of it: you're taking a user's overly specific problem and boiling it down to the core of it, then explaining how to deal with it.

You might also notice that I wrote that question. I did not write that question because I needed the answer (as evidenced by the fact that I wrote that too;) ). I did not write that question/answer just because I wanted to have that said somewhere; I could easily have written that answer on one of the dozens of such duplicates.

No, I wrote that question/answer for the expressed purpose of *creating a dupe-target*, of having a single, centralized, canonical question/answer to all of the myriad of forms of this question.

If you had told me then that, while I would be allowed to write such a canonical question, I would not be allowed to actually *use it* for its intended purpose, that I would be prevented from voting to dupe-hammering to it, then I probably wouldn't have written it. I'd have just picked some other, more specific version of the question to use as a dupe target.

And the site would be worse off for it.

You're basically saying that a person who frequents a tag often enough to know what questions get asked frequently, and then takes the time to write a canonical question/answer for it, will not have the power to dupe-hammer duplicates of that canonical question. This is particularly important on tags with relatively low user participation, where it's already hard to get questions closed as duplicates in reasonable time.

Comment: I was about to write the second half of this answer myself. Disabling the hammer for questions I've answered would make me at least half as effective in the relatively small tag I'm a top answerer of. If I add an answer to a canonical, I can no longer use it. If I come across a novel question that I think others will ask in the future, I can't answer it if I want to use it as a canonical.

Comment: As I [wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303979) about the hammer back in 2015, "The whole idea is that users who earn privileges are able to make the right decision. If any abuse were to happen, I'm confident someone would catch it and we'd hear about it right here on Meta."

Answer (score 10):

It has been a little while since I closed that as a dupe. I've closed many other Bootstrap 4 Navbar alignment questions as there has been the same type of Navbar alignment questions asked over and over again.

The closed [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178386) is *very* specific to a BS 4 alpha which was non flexbox Navbar. Yes, the accepted answer did eventually [evolve](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40193892/revisions) over time as BS 4 progressed (after I posted the Jan 17 answer to the beta flexbox relevant question), but it no longer addressed the very specific BS 4 alpha question of a Navbar that wasn't it any way structured like the proper post alpha6/beta/4.0.0 flexbox Navbar. The structure of the Navbar in the original accepted answer is completely different.

Earlier this year, when I closed as dupe, I most likely thought that SO users in search of "Bootstrap 4 Navbar align" answers would find the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463) more helpful as it wasn't specific to pre-flexbox alpha, and IMO was a better, more up-to-date question. It clearly describes all of the users' attempts to solve the problem, and is not specifically tied to a very old alpha version.

It may appear that I closed as dupe to benefit my own answer, but I can ensure you it was to prevent users from asking the same old Bootstrap 4 Navbar alignment questions again and again. That I think is more beneficial to the community as a whole.

*For the record...*

> "A similar question is posted and answered Jan 6 '17 at 20:25 by "User
>   X". That answer is no different from the "original" answer made by
>   "User Zero" back in '16."

This is not true. When I answered in Jan 17 the older Oct 16 question was already out of date for Bootstrap 4 beta and had not been updated. My original flexbox alignment answer was very different than the other accepted answer which at that time used floats.

> Now, Feb 22 '18 at 14:12 "User X" marks the old question as a
>   duplicate of the newer question and by that his own accepted answer..
>   The answer from '17 does not bring any new not already covered by the
>   question from '16 and its accepted answer.

No. Again the newer question and accepted answer are more relevant since the release of Bootstrap 4 (the time at which I closed the old question as dupe). The other answer was eventually brought up-to-date which made it out-of-sync with the original alpha version question, which IMO confuses users even more. You can see the confusion in the comments. You can also see the other answer was only brought up-to-date *after* other beta relevant answers were posted (similar to my answer in the newer question).

If the questions are dupes of each other, regardless of chronological order, the better question shouldn't be closed. This is because future readers are more likely to get the correct answer from the better (more up-to-date, relevant) question. Therefore, preventing yet another dupe question.

Comment: I see many, many, many duplicates on the datatables tag. I believe 70% of the questions somehow is answered in various way, many, many times before. For example by myself. But I do not browse around and mark new questions and answers as duplicates of the old similar ones.  You say it will "*prevent users from asking the same old Bootstrap 4 Navbar alignment questions again and again*". Exactly how does it prevent new questions to be asked, that you mark some already asked and answered questions as duplicate to another already asked and answered ..?

Comment: I really dont see how it should prevent anything. In my experience it does not work this way. New users asks often because they not understand the subject and dont know how to google an answer.  A lot of people just sit an wait to answer, and they dont care that there already is 10 similar answers (they even some times copy / paste your old "canonical" answer).  So I really cannot see how you altruistic or self-sacrificing helps future users nor Stackoverflow here :)

Comment: I don't browse around and look for old questions either. Sometimes a user (often new) will post a question like "I tried this question/answer [here] but it's not working" and that's most likely how I discovered the dupe Once the old question is closed as dupe, users can now follow the dup link in addition to find alternative answers. Doesn't that make them less likely to post the same question again?

Comment: But thank you for answering! I must **emphasize** that I have nothing against you personally, it is the general "idea" of how we are using the dupe hammer I am heading for ...

Comment: YW and yes, I agree. I just think that preventing older questions from being closed as dupe of newer questions would be a mistake. I also don't know why people get so upset about the dupe hammer. It's simply offering other answers to the same question. The closed original Q/A can still be updated and maintained as needed.

Comment: Yes, Agree - I just suggest we need a "solution". It degrades the entire credibility of SO. If your "trick" becomes a popular way to highlight own answers above old perfectly good answers we have taken the gameification of the Q&A concept to a new level that is counter constructive.  Personally and honestly I go for reps like you, it is the entire goal, but I use the dupe hammer to prevent "noise", stupid questions and all those already asked questions.  And I do not use the dupe hammer if I only can point to one of my own answers, if that is the case I just drop a comment, "see xxxx".

Comment: It's not your fault that the better dupe target had an answer of yours on it. That's part of having the dupe hammer.  It may be possible to put [protection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372428/3956566) in place for gold badgers.

Comment: There should probably be a new state for answers separate from "duplicate". Instead of "this is a duplicate of x" there should be "there is a more updated question at y" which doesn't invalidate the old question and answers. I don't know where to go to suggest such a thing.

Comment: @AlecGordon, interesting idea. But that would ruin the whole point with "duplicated answers" and the dupe hammer.  And in Denmark we have a saying: "you cannot be half pregnant". When I mark questions as duplicated I sometimes eager for feedback. It is nice to see that people get an exact answer for their problem, and nice to see the old answer get an upvote. To me, this is the whole point with stackoverflow (to be dramatic and exaggerated) I really like that. I hate the flow of the same answers and questions again and again ...