# Closing an old upvoted question as duplicate of new unvoted questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I posted a question over seven years ago, and over the years it received a hundred upvotes, and also has an answer with a hundred upvotes.

Today I received a message that the question was closed as duplicate, and the associated questions were all much newer and were not upvoted at all. Moreover, the original question was protected by the community.

Why was this done? How do you decide which question is the "original" and which is the duplicate? This makes no sense to me. What am I missing?

Here's a link to the question: *[Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet)*

Comment: The better question with the better answer(s) is the preferred duplicate target. Time of posting is never a consideration. Do the answers in the duplicates answer your question? If they do then nothing is broken.

Comment: Worth considering: Is the content of the earlier question still up to date, or are answer code/approaches outdated?

Comment: For this specific case, it seems odd, though, since the older version appears to have more answers and the answers there are of good quality afaict. If there's a more recent better approach in one of the newer duplicates that should be added to the old question imo.

Comment: Yeah, that's my point, how do you decide which is "better"? I'd say look at stats, upvotes, favorites, etc - but then 3 questions with 0 upvotes were left open while the most upvoted with the most popular answer was closed.

Comment: It is either decided a) hastily/randomly or b) because the dupe target contains an objectively better answer. The latter generally is pretty obvious when you look at an answer and it nearly blinds you.

Comment: *"I'd say look at stats, upvotes, favorites, etc"* - That favours _older_ questions, not necessarily better.

Comment: @Nick is correct. A question that is 5 years old will almost always have more upvotes than any newer question. So, it's not very fair to base "what is better" on that. Although, you can get the opposite situation, too - a newer question becomes hot and receivers more upvotes in return, although the response(s) provide less information than what can be found in an older question. There is no site metric that can be used for "better" - it has to be evaluated by a human. And in some cases, it's a bit of a coin flip. However, any link is usually better than fragmented information.

Comment: While I agree with @Nick, I still fail to see why all the target questions are answered by the same user, or why is the caching issue not addressed by any of those.

Comment: I agree. The linked questions should be closed as duplicates of yours if anything. Voted to re-open.

Comment: I can't tell you how many closed questions I have come across which don't accept new answers as they are "duplicates" but the linked duplicate has a horrible title which isn't utilizing the correct keywords and the question is way broader/unclear. Many, many w/ 100K views and not accepting new answers... :(

Comment: It looks like the gold badge holder that closed it had previously attempted to do the duplicate closure [the other way round in 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56893480/73226) but presumably before they got the gold badge so this was unsuccessful and aged away. I guess likely they did it this way round as they had already used their vote in the opposite direction

Comment: @rene - "*The better question with the better answer(s) is the preferred duplicate target*" - the only objective indication of "better" I can think of is how useful something is to the community, and AFAIK that is expressed in upvotes.  Outside that, how can you even quantify something like "better" Q&A?  How does one arrive at the conclusion that a new answer with 0 upvotes is **better** than it's predecessor with 86k views and 100 upvotes? This strikes me as a *highly* subjective policy on a network that greatly discourages opinion based activity.

Comment: @billynoah (what about [Nick's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404535/closing-an-old-upvoted-question-as-duplicate-of-new-unvoted-questions?cb=1#comment819757_404535)?)

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers (that's a separate issue, and it looks like that you can either edit the target question to make it better, or ask some mod to reverse the duplicate closure.)

Comment: @rene +1. You should post an answer based on your first comment. This is so true. As a community, we don't care about who was first, the only thing that matters is the content quality. If the new question has better wording and/or better answers, this one should be the main, and the others duplicates. Time of posting is unrelevant.

Comment: @Basj "As a community, we don't care about who was first..." Depends on the circumstances. For newly asked questions without answers, we care about who was first. I wonder if we should simply merge answers of truly duplicate questions and leave the questions as pointers to the answers. In that way we would truly not care about who came first.

Comment: @Trilarion "For newly asked questions without answers, ..." Yes, of course. In such cases, I think we will all agree to close the new one as duplicate, there is no discussion for such cases. That's why I added " If the new question *has better wording and/or better answers*..."

Comment: @Basj "I think we will all agree to close the new one as duplicate, there is no discussion for such cases." I fully agree, even though it means that we do take time into account. In principle I could come and say, hey I can ask that question better than some other user, so I will ask it and then close his/her question as duplicate of mine. That would be the true meaning of time of posting is irrelevant. But we shouldn't do it like that. We should concentrate on improving existing content first.

Answer (score 39):

**Don't close big questions as duplicates of small ones, improve the big one instead**

I recommend not closing big questions (lots of votes/views/answers) as duplicates of smaller ones, [regardless of which one was asked first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha), but rather the other way around, with the following rationale.

First, when a question is big, it means that more people have contributed to it with answers, comments and votes. Therefore, by closing it, you are wasting the time of more people who have contributed to the larger one, which makes people not want to contribute anymore.

Every big question has 10 small duplicates, which are extremely hard to find all of. Therefore, it is extremely hard to determine which of those 10 small questions is the best canonical based on best answers. If a gold badge user comes along and somehow determines that one of those small ones is the canonical, the choice is extremely unpredictable to other users. This makes it extremely hard to determine where to contribute to.

Next, the big old question always has the higher Google Pagerank. Therefore, people will land there first, and it is more productive if instead we correct existing answers with edits, possibly linking to better answers, or write new better answers, rather than requiring users to click the duplicate link.

What often happens is that the big old question is closed because a new library/language version became available and provided a better answer, or invalidated old ones. And the new question has a few highly upvoted answers, with the new shiny answer newer to the top.

But this does not scale. Imagine that in the future, the small answer becomes big, and yet another library/language feature comes along and becomes the better answer. What will we do then? Create a third one? This is messy.

Also, not all people might have access to the newest version of said library, so maybe the old answers still have some value.

This is why I recommend to always stick to the the big one, and concentrate all information in one single more obvious place.

The underlying problem is of course that the answer sorting algorithm is too naive: direct upvote count. The real solution to the problem is to take into account the answer age: a newer answer with X votes should show up before an older answer with X votes, because it gets more votes per unit of time. SE developers must read this: https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Comment: But closing a question as a duplicate does not delete it. The question will still be editable. Answers are still editable. In conclusion, no prior contribution is wasted. Everything is still there. Even more, the state is not static. It can be reopened. It is a dynamic process. Nothing is final. Nothing should be final nor dictated. Even Google page ranking is not constant ;-)

Comment: @Thomas regardless of deletion, you still fell like wasting your time when the question has a huge "Duplicate of" on top. I wonder what percentage of Googlers actually click that link though. I believe that in practice, the PageRank of a small question never overcome that of the big question. And duplicate closures of big questions are basically decided only by gold badge users that come along, so they change rarely as well. On the other hand, it does mean that if you have answered, you are protected from competition from new answers :-)

Comment: I switched the accepted answer to this one, since I agree with this reasoning more. However since this is kind of a discussion on how Stack Exchange should behave, I'm not sure if it's up to me to decide which is the correct answer... Maybe just leave the question open?

Comment: @tbkn23 I recommend not accepting either. Accept is a broken feature anyways ;-) Voters should always decide.

Comment: Improving the big question is often impractical. In particular, there can be several wrong or obsolete answers (or ones that would become impractical to fix, if the question were properly edited to meet current standards) that have hundreds of upvotes each.

Comment: Indeed, old questions are often very messy, ambiguous, mention several problems at once with each answer replying only to one part… and that’s before we count users posting at best tenuously related answers, in hopes of piggybacking off a popular question to earn some Internet points or promote their pet project. And there’s often no way to improve that without invalidating the numerous already-written answers. I wish there was a way to “retire” old questions and suggest they be re-asked from scratch. Closing older questions as duplicates of newer ones seems like the closest thing to that.

Answer (score 31):

I was the close voter and I decided that the answers in the linked duplicates were better than the answers in the original question. The vote is currently overturned by the community.

The old thread was more popular. However, The top voted answer in the older thread is not the best now(Because it uses a direct  extra cell reference. I believed the linked answers using formula name change automatically, using a trigger, without  using a extra cell was much better). Also, the thread had [a outright wrong answer, which never worked, but was upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37829242/). Similar questions were asked multiple times, most recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65755314/). Those who ask tend to receive better answers than those who search.

Note that closing as duplicate doesn't hide your question(especially, when closed with multiple duplicates). Your answer and question will still be visible, but with a banner that states that this question has answers here(with the linked duplicates). The intention was to expose users coming across this thread to better answers. Having said that, I agree that the linked questions (not the answers) are not of better quality than the older thread and I agree that my close vote is controversial.

Comment: Not that I think there's anything wrong with having a newer, better canonical, but why don't you improve the top answer to the old question?

Comment: @oguzismail The old top answer uses a entirely different approach. I don't think it's appropriate to rewrite the original answer, which still works. I also did add a similar new-approach answer to the older thread. But after a while, closing it seemed like a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your reasoning. I'm not sure I agree the answers for the linked questions are better - since they require you to hard-code the formula into the script. So I guess that's the main point of this question - who/how do you decide which question/answer is better? I thought that was the whole point of the upvoting system, to float up good answers and questions. But then suddenly someone decides differently, that's not how I expected Stack Exchange to work.

Comment: @tbkn23  3 users  are needed to  form  any decision: close as duplicate or reopen. But Gold badge users like me(>1000 score on the tag) can close/reopen with just 1 vote. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298807/ Of course my decision can be overruled by the community(3 users)  or another gold badge  holder

Comment: If @tbkn23 included a link to the "better" one in his answer with a brief explanation, wouldn't it solve the problem here?

Comment: @tbkn23 Also Just FYI, The timeline icon on the left of all posts show all the actions/voters. For eg: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/404535/timeline

Comment: closing as duplicate does "hide your question" for anonymous users AFAIK. They get transparently redirected to the dupe. Or at least it used to work that way

Comment: @MartinSmith I tested it and it didn't redirect as it had 2-3 duplicates linked.

Comment: @MartinSmith as long as there's no answer and linked to a single question.

Comment: If a merge would be appropriate, I'm happy to perform one. But the questions need to be truly identical, such that the answers to one would fit perfectly as answers to the other.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, but I don't think the merge would be appropriate as the answers linked are a bit more specific to that question and they won't fit perfectly.

Comment: "I was the close voter and I decided that the answers in the linked duplicates were better than the answers in the original question." That's interesting. A duplicate question lived and attracted better answers than the original question. In principle it should have been closed as duplicate before it attracted any answers at all and better answers should have been posted on the original question but maybe there they would have been ignored. Your way was an ingenious solution to get a high quality answer to the top quickly, even though it kind of defeats the rules. ...

Comment: ... The general problem is simply that content ages and votes from the past aren't really carrying the same weight as more recent votes. We could simply merge answers from duplicate questions (and merge duplicate questions) and weigh votes with age. That way the best answer to a question even if it comes much later had a chance to rise to the top.

Comment: @Trilarion: And this inertia is also a problem when trying to improve an existing answer. Any new answer -- potentially using a new method not available at the time -- starts with a score of 0, so is way down, and because it's way down, few people ever bother scrolling that far to see it, and upvote it, so it lingers. When new versions of a library/language/... allow new answers, you either need the top-answer to be edited (best done by its author) or a new question; that's the only way to avoid "losing" good answers. Sad :(

Answer (score 6):

> Why was this done? How do you decide which question is the "original" and which is the duplicate? This makes no sense to me. What am I missing?

There is no such thing as "the original". When closing posts as duplicates, we should strive to preserve the post with the best question and the highest quality content in the answers. Post date and votes should not matter.

*However*, old posts with some 50+ score should be treated carefully, since a lot of people apparently found them helpful. If new high quality answers pop up under some duplicate question, then those answers should perhaps have been merged into the existing one. Before closing down such posts as duplicates, I would poke other high rep users in the tag and look for consensus, maybe bring it up on meta.

Also note that we should avoid picking a dupe target where we are partial, ie we are the poster of the question or one of the answers (and it's not a community wiki). This isn't explicitly forbidden, but usually frowned upon by the community. In such cases it is better to *propose* that your post might be a good duplicate target by leaving a comment, then let other high rep users cast the actual votes and decide if it should be closed.

Comment: By "Original" I meant the one that is left open and is linked to when closing as duplicate. What you're saying about consulting others or opening a meta post makes much sense to me. I do disagree that votes should not matter, since like you said yourself, votes are the measure of people finding it helpful, ignoring that is ignoring the only hard objective data that you have.

Comment: Could you provide a source/community consensus for stating that it is "frowned upon by the community"?  Although I didn't add duplicate targets where I was the owner of question/answer in this particular case, I wrote questions and answers for the explicit purpose of being dupe targets and I think it is ok.

Comment: Time elapsed is also a valuable measure. A question that was asked years ago with many views tells me that the answers are more likely to represent the range of possible answers than a short-lived question.

Comment: @TheMaster In a 2018 discussion i remember taking part in, there were quite a few frowns, but no consensus. (FWIW, I side with [deceze's answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367464/2751851), which argues we perhaps should trust our hammer-wielders a little more.)

Comment: @TheMaster It's common sense and decency? Other than that, there's been plenty of such discussions on meta over the years, particularly about the gold badge "dupe hammer".

Comment: @Lundin There have been discussions, but it's not frowned upon or considered "not decent". You're given authority and you're free to use it for the gain of community. Conflict of interest is unavoidable as you know where your answers are and how it answers the question(being a gold badge holder).  Avoiding/delaying closing(because you're one of the answerers) will only propagate the problem of diversification of good quality answers  for the same question.

Comment: @TheMaster The give an example, the canonical dupe for the single-most common FAQ below the C and C++ tags is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior), currently sitting at Q: +839 votes and top A: +579 votes. I don't think this post is particularly good because the complete detailed answered is scattered across multiple answers and the top-voted one is quite incomplete. ->

Comment: Therefore I decided to write a more detailed and complete self-answered Q&A which is currently only available at Codidact: [Why can't we mix increment operators like i++ with other operators?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278384). This post is, in my very personal opinion, much better than the scattered answers in the canonical dupe above. ->

Comment: Now lets assume I post a copy of my post here on SO. I don't make it community wiki but claim all rep for the question and answer for myself. I then go to the 800+ voted dupe and close that as a dupe of my own post, because my own post is in my own opinion of higher technical quality. Then I run off to close all the thousands of FAQ posts about this issue (this question is usually asked around 5 times per week or so) pointing them all to my own self-answered Q&A. I would be getting hundreds of votes in no time. Do you seriously not see how immoral this would be?

Comment: @Lundin I don't think you'll be getting hundreds of votes, regardless of your answer quality. I dare you to try and see :) In any case, There's a balance. There are other badge holders and community members, who would vote to reopen the FAQs in no time. I don't think your hypothetical scenario is feasible. If in your opinion, there's a potential gain to the community, do it => if the community disagrees your votes are overturned. The majority opinion always rules. This isn't much different from commenting your answer link under each post and asking the community to close it.

Comment: @TheMaster I've written various self-answered Q&A converted to community wikis, that I do use as dupe target (along with other users), [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ) is from 2016 and is currently 16th most frequent post of all time below the C tag. One big reason for this is that I've been personally active moderating the C tag by using dupe hammers. It sits at ~50 score but then C is a medium traffic tag, imagine doing the same below the highest traffic tags like Java or C# etc.

Answer (score 0):

As someone that got the ball rolling towards further discussing this question, I believe that the title is misguided. There's no problem with the directionality of the closing, but I have to really wonder if these questions are really a duplicate of 3 other questions.

Personally, I see two different questions when someone asks "How to do X", and "I'm doing Y, that should work in theory to solve X, but it doesn't solve it due Y". On these questions, I fail to see how they are asking the same thing, other than using custom functions.

Yes, I know that the solution is around `createTextFinder`, but the use of a single function is not enough to say that these are duplicate. But how about the high level view of the solution: look for the formula, replace the formula. Well, as the [close voter admits on a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404535/closing-an-old-upvoted-question-as-duplicate-of-new-unvoted-questions?cb=1#comment820076_404555), the answers are "more specific" and they "won't fit perfectly" on one another. That's enough to say that one answer won't answer the other question without non-trivial work by the reader of the answer.

I would like to be shown wrong, but while the "why the problem occurs" seems to be shared, the specific "how to solve this" is different, due the different angle in which the underlying issue becomes relevant.

Comment: (1/2) I would like to clarify that the author of those answers made it a bit more specific. For eg, the third duplicate starts with [`You want to recalculate the custom function of =findRate(), when the cells of the sheet name of Rates are edited.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56895168/). Now without  the question itself, you wouldn't know what `findRate()` even is and  the answer would seem unseemly on this old question. Again, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61946592), the author focuses on performance, but the underlying strategy would be the same. I could probably edit them all to shape

Comment: (2/2)to fit the older question, but, I'm not sure whether that's the right way . Having added a answer myself, I decided to link them in my answer instead.

Comment: Also note that original asker of the old thread doesn't  dispute that  the answers solve the problem. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404535/closing-an-old-upvoted-question-as-duplicate-of-new-unvoted-questions/404581?noredirect=1#comment819934_404555) and [silence here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404535/closing-an-old-upvoted-question-as-duplicate-of-new-unvoted-questions/404581?noredirect=1#comment819743_404535)

Comment: I'll just note that my question was specifically about how to choose *which* question to close, and not how to decide if questions are identical or not. So I wouldn't say the title is misguided (at least not based on my original intent in asking it)