# Seeking advice on flagging older questions as duplicates of a new canonical Post

Tags: discussion, canonical

I have recently created a detailed, canonical question and answer regarding a common issue in Flutter: [Flutter FutureBuilder keeps Firing and rebuilding. It Generates a New Random Number on Every Rebuild - How can I Prevent This?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/12349734).

This post is intended to serve as a comprehensive guide on the subject.

In reviewing older posts, I've come across several questions that cover similar ground ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56424828/12349734), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77755908/12349734)). While these questions are somewhat similar, they might not encompass the breadth of information or the specific nuances addressed in the canonical post.

In light of this new canonical question, I am seeking advice on the best practices for flagging older, related questions as duplicates. My goal is to help users find the most accurate and comprehensive information efficiently. However, I also want to respect the contributions and nuances in the older questions.

**Question**

In the process of consolidating knowledge with my new canonical post, I am faced with a decision: should I flag older questions that seem to be covered by the comprehensive scope of my new post?

Comment: Related: [Closing an old upvoted question as duplicate of new unvoted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404535/2745495), [Old question marked as duplicate of a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315472/2745495)

Comment: Given your reputation score, I assume by "flagging as duplicate" you mean "voting to close as duplicate", yes?

Comment: @M.Justin Right. I mean to vote close.

Comment: "these questions are somewhat similar" If they are only similar but not identical, closing as duplicates may not be the right thing. At the very least one can link to each other. Also "the comprehensive scope of my new post" should not make your new question too broad. It should still focus on an issue and be answerable within a post of reasonable length.

Answer (score 6):

"Covering similar ground" is not the same thing as a duplicate.  You should mark questions as duplicate only when the question is actually the same.  I'm no expert in Flutter, but the questions look quite different to me, the titles barely use any overlapping phrases.

Additionally, closing duplicates to questions that you yourself have both asked and answered could appear to be reputation farming.  You are limiting the votes on other people's questions and answers and pointing everybody to your own.  I'd let other people close duplicates in a case like this, or get your question and answer marked as community wiki so that you don't gain reputation from it.

Comment: "You should mark questions as duplicate only when the question is actually the same"  Not at all - you should use duplicates when there is another post which answers the question. Quite often when asking a debug question, the OP doesn't know what the problem is while asking, so comparing the question to another question is often not meaningful. For example "why am I getting a segmentation fault/null pointer exception" etc questions should ideally be closed as dupe to a post explaining the root cause of the problem. And not just some generic post about seg faults or null pointer exceptions.

Comment: @Lundin This looks like a 'well actually' response. Even in your own example of "why am I getting this seg fault" - we all know there is context to the question which is similar to another but isn't the same.

Comment: @DavidFisher So the decision is best left to someone with domain knowledge, like a gold badge dupe hammer. If you know what the problem in the question is and you know of a duplicate that addresses it, then it should be closed as dupe. However, there may be multiple issues in the question - either they are all FAQ after which a gold badger can add multiple dupe targets - or one of the issues is unique to the question, in which case it is better to leave it open.

Comment: If there are multiple questions in one post, it should be closed as "needs focus."  The question should be edited to remove all but the one question before it is re-opened for answering.

Comment: Questions can sometimes look very different and still be the same, so yes it is up to domain experts to recognize that.  However, in this case the OP is a domain expert and said the questions are "covering similar ground" not "describing the same problem in different ways" or even "having different symptoms of the same underlying cause."