# Better inform gold-badge holders that if they want to add different or other dupes, they can edit the list instead of reopening the question

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Gold badge holders have the option to edit the question's dup-target list, as described in [What should I do as a gold badge holder if I feel the duplicate target isn't the right one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355666/what-should-i-do-as-a-gold-badge-holder-if-i-feel-the-duplicate-target-isnt-the) Unfortunately, there are a considerable number of gold-badge holders who don't appear to be aware of their ability to edit the dup-target list.

Just as a quality-of-life change, it would be nice to inform gold-badge holders that they should edit the list if they think the dupes are wrong, as opposed to reopening and re-hammering a duplicate question.  This would allow more people to take full advantage of the feature.

So, let's add a feature, in addition to the small "edit" text in the dup-target list, that actively informs gold-badge holders that they have the option to edit the dup-target list, rather than open and reclose the question.

Comment: Are you seeing a lot of actual gold-badge holders reopening duplicates for that reason?

Comment: It happens often enough that it's irksome, so yes @NicolBolas.

Comment: ... why do I feel that the question is because of a sudden reaction? The usual Makoto touch isn't there. But yeah, perhaps when a gold badge holder clicks on the "reopen" on a post they have closed, a pop asking about whether they want to update the list, would be a good idea.

Comment: Ideas on how to inform them? Maybe [a hero](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357858/dont-clutter-half-the-screen-with-things-most-people-dont-care-for?noredirect=1)? Or [the standard mechanism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification)?

Comment: @BhargavRao:  You're *absolutely* right!  It is also late here and there's enough in the way of straws on this ol' camel's back right now.  It's still a QoS kind of thing, and I feel like I don't really need a whole *lot* of explanation...but I won't hide the fact that this is definitely knee-jerk.  That's not to say that this hasn't happened before, but y'know...

Comment: @CodyGray:  Probably something along the lines of, if you're a gold badge holder and you vote to reopen, you get more of a warning dialog than "Are you sure...?", explaining that if you don't like the dupe targets, then you could simply *edit* the list instead of reopening the question.  Nothing too fancy, really.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links

Comment: by the way, if you reopen you cannot reclose again.

Comment: eh, you can, if you weren't the one that initially closed it. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do as a gold badge holder if I feel the duplicate target isn't the right one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355666/what-should-i-do-as-a-gold-badge-holder-if-i-feel-the-duplicate-target-isnt-the). It's been there for a while, and I know the author well enough :)

Comment: I sometimes reopen questions on purpose, because they are closed with a flat-out wrong target. Afterwards I hammer them down with the canonical question on the topic."Editing the list only" feels like giving an approval to the original close-voter.

Comment: @Bergi: what does that change? that you have your name as the closer instead of the original closer? what if the original closer does the same (reopens?).

Comment: [algorithm] gold badge holder here, TIL.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, the outcome isn't much different for the asker. I'm doing it for the statistics only, hoping that someone counts closures that were later reopened differently :-) If the original close voter disagrees, we'll have a discussion in the comments. And don't forget: I'm not advocating this, I'm just giving a possible reason.

Comment: @Bergi: yes, it's your right.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is a duplicate of the [current dup-target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355666/3773011). That dup-target is asking what a gold-badge holder can/should do when the dup-target is wrong. This question is a feature request asking for a change in the system to better inform gold-badge holders that they have the option to edit the list of dup-targets (i.e. to better inform them that what's described in this question's current dup-target is an option for them). While they are related, they are different questions.

Comment: I'm a moderator and even I forget this all the time.

Comment: @BoltClock for you it's the same as you can close/reopen as many times as you want

Comment: It would have been helpful if this feature was announced when it was released, because I don't recall ever getting poked about it - it was suddenly just there. I didn't even realize it was for gold badgers only, I thought it was for anyone with edit privileges. Do you at least get informed when you earn a new gold badge?

Answer (score 9):

Why not just change the "nominate that question for reopening" confirmation popup to adapt to gold badge owners when clicking on "reopen" ? Something like:

> Reopen this question ? Note that if you're reopening because you have a better original candidate, you can add or change it by clicking on the "edit" duplicate button instead

So if someone wants to reopen to close with another dupe, just present them with alternate options.

Comment: [I believe that's *exactly* what I'm proposing.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380482/better-inform-gold-badge-holders-that-if-they-want-to-add-different-or-other-dup/380555#comment672306_380482)  At least now it's codified in an answer.

Comment: oh right, TL;DR ! converted to CW. Same idea. Will probably be coded in a few weeks then (6 or 8 to be exact)