# If I mark a question as duplicate and then reopen it by mistake, I can no longer close it as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

If I close a question as duplicate, and then re-open it, I can no longer mark it as duplicate:

[image]

Is this a bug?  Or is just the question of me having to wait a little longer?

Comment: No, that's not a bug. It's by design.

Comment: If you want to change dupes, edit the dupe list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Close Questions privilege help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, **but each individual user may cast at most one close and one reopen vote per question**.

(Emphasis mine).

Just be more careful with your close/reopen votes. Particularly if you are wielding a hammer.

If your intention was to change the dupe target (and assuming this happened on a question with a tag you are gold badge holder), remember you can instead [edit the duplicate list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355666/what-should-i-do-as-a-gold-badge-holder-if-i-feel-the-duplicate-target-isnt-the?noredirect=1&lq=1). Much better and practical than attempting to reopen and close again.

Comment: "Just be more careful with your close/reopen votes.", there is also the case where you VTC a bad post, OP edits, then it's a dupe and you can't close... That happens very frequently, and it's not because of lack of carefulness in handling our votes.

Comment: It's a possibility. But if the post needs closing anyway, I wouldn't lose sleep over that vote. Either retract and let other users handle it, or just let your vote stand and be counted for closure. The majority of the votes will determine what closure banner is shown anyway.