# Let users vote to close again after automatically retracted close votes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

### Let users vote to close again after *automatically retracted* close votes

- X posts a question Q with some information.
- Later, X posts question Q'.

  - (*Q' is essentially the same as Q, but Q and Q' provide different information.  The combination of the two might provide enough information reproduce a problem or answer the question.*)
- Y votes to close Q' as a duplicate of Q.
- X deletes Q, but doesn't update Q'.
- Y's close vote is *automatically* retracted.
- Y can't vote to close Q' again.

  - (*When both Q and Q' existed, it would have been possible to merge the two and produce an answerable question.  Now that only Q' is available, it's no longer a duplicate, but it certainly doesn't have enough information.*)

I'd propose that in this case, Y should be able to vote to close Q' since the close vote was *automatically*, not *voluntarily*, retracted.

### Background

Today, a user posted a question that was  variant of a question they'd asked yesterday.  Between the two questions, there might have been enough information to come up with an answer.  I voted to close the latter as a duplicate of the former, and left a comment to the user that rather than posting a new question, that the appropriate course of action would have been to edit the original question. The user deleted the earlier question (and it was good that at least one of the two should be deleted).  However, the user didn't merge the content of the two, leaving the remaining question incomplete and without enough information to reproduce the problem.  I went to close vote for that reason, but found that I couldn't, as I had already voted to close as a duplicate.  I understand the general reason for not allowing votes after voluntary retraction (e.g., see [Why can't we vote to close a question after the original vote was retracted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254778/why-cant-we-vote-to-close-a-question-after-the-original-vote-was-retracted)), but this is a case where the close vote was *automatically* removed by the system because the possible duplicate was deleted.

Comment: You could edit Q' to include the deleted information in Q.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Yes, I personally can (and almost did), since I can see deleted content, but that's not a general solution since not everyone can do that.  If it weren't for the "possible duplicate of ..." comment, I wouldn't be able to get to the deleted question at all.  The content in Q actually needed a bit of improvement, too (and I'd commented to that extent).  Neither question was particularly good, but the second question seemed like the sort of thing that was meant to be an update to the first, and with a bit of work, the combination could have been a reasonable question.

Comment: It's a general solution for the specific condition of having information split between the two questions.  The OP is probably not experienced enough in the ways of SO to do it himself, and of course it takes someone who can see the deleted content.  As for your general suggestion, I don't disagree.

Comment: Actually, that raises another issue:  if someone votes to close A as a possible duplicate of B, and then B is deleted, the close vote is automatically retracted, but the comment isn't deleted.  I'd think that the comment should probably be deleted, too, if the vote is being retracted.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Re **The OP is probably not experienced enough in the ways of SO to do it himself**:  it may be the case, but I'd expect most users that can find the "delete" link to be able to find the "edit" link, too.  I meant that it's not a general solution for two reasons:  (i) it can't be performed by everyone that can cast close votes, because not all of them can see deleted content; and (ii) in general, once the other question is deleted, there's no way to get to it again (in this case, there's the "possible duplicate of ..." comment, but that can be deleted too).

Comment: By "you" above, I really meant you, and was not thinking of close-voters who can no longer see the deleted question.  Good point.  And as I said, I don't disagree with the general suggestion that you are making.

Comment: Sounds like a great situation to raise a custom flag. "I've run into an edge case scenario and I can't do anything. Can you please do this or this to resolve the situation?" Do these circumstances really occur that often that you'd need to modify a core behavior of close votes to account for it?

Comment: It's a big problem on Area 51 with the aging of close votes on example questions, with no close vote queue to keep the votes alive. I often find myself flagging questions I previously voted to close but my close vote expires. In fact, IMO, most closed example questions are closed by moderator action and not by five users. More info on Area 51 Discussion Zone: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/17511/dont-age-close-votes-on-example-questions (@animuson)

Comment: consider [edit]ing to describe how do you expect system to work in case if user (or privileged voters, or moderator) decides to _undelete_ later

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi That's a completely different situation than what is explained in this request, and I would be adamently against any modification that would allow users to re-cast close votes simply because they've expired.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi As animuson points out, that's really a different situation.  I agree that there's definitely some difficulty there, and I don't spend much time in Area 51, but I see it in a number of the tags that I'm active in that tend to have low viewership.  Getting questions closed can be difficult.  That said, it's a different scenario from this one.

Comment: @gnat That's sort of an interesting point.  If Y votes to close Q' as a dupe of Q, and then Q is deleted, Y's vote is automatically retracted.  If Q is then undeleted, does the current system un-retract  the close vote?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I think it's possible to test this right here, at meta :)

Comment: @gnat Come on now, this is a site about Stack Overflow, not about debugging the behavior of complex software systems that we only have indirect access to… oh.

Comment: tell Shadow Wizard that our [recent testing of comment flags at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237342/does-flagging-a-comment-as-other-count-as-a-vote-to-delete-it#comment778039_237342) was wrong way :)

Comment: @animuson Oh, I thought that automatic retraction also included aging...but the non-presence of a close vote review queue on A51 means that the purpose of aging there is unclear.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Yeah, I guess that's true;  the expiration *is* a sort of automatic retraction.  It's not the one that I meant here though.  Good catch on the overlap, though!

Comment: Oh, and don't forget recommend closure flags dismissed as "removed during a deletion"...