# "Red dot" the review button when there's a reopen vote on a question you closed, and put it at start of queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, user-interface

I  easily lose track of questions I voted to close. Today I came back across a question I voted to close, and it has been fixed, but I can't answer it now until enough other people come along to vote on it. It's not on a high-traffic tag, so it might take days.

If a question has been edited to make it valid, it could have a faster path to reopening if the original close-voters look at it. They've already invested a bit of time in reviewing the question and can more quickly evaluate if the issue has been fixed.

On a related note, it might help if people who voted to close can double-vote to reopen. These people are the least likely to unnecessarily reopen a question.

For this reason I propose that the reopen review queue prioritize questions you closed, and show the red dot at the top. This would be far less intrusive than [showing a notification for each instance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372431/notification-to-closers-when-question-is-proposed-for-reopening). You would only get the notification if someone else has already come by and voted to reopen, so it would cut way down on how frequently these happened. And the notifications would all be rolled into one red dot on the review queue, instead of multiple inbox items.

If you prefer only to "[take out the trash](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372432/506796)" or work on the close queue (which is respectable considering it's the more pressing problem), you can just ignore the reopen queue as usual.

Comment: Excellent idea! When I (occasionally) come across a post in the reopen queue that I voted to close, and it's been suitably edited 'into shape', I actually get something of a feel-good hit from the fact that I can then add my reopen vote.

Comment: The overall question here is: *Do we want reopen reviews to be done independently from close-votes / -reviews.* I understand there would be advantages to the people who close-voted also doing the question's reopen reviews (e.g. evaluating changes would be done by people already familiar with the question, who wouldn't necessarily need to spend as much time as someone coming at the question cold; in many cases, those people would know exactly what additional info the question needs; etc.). OTOH, there are advantages of reopen reviews being independent (people with other POVs see the question).