# Should you be able to change your close vote reason on a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently saw this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098242/how-to-read-n-lines-of-text-as-a-char-in-c#34098242

It started out as just:

> I want to read N, then N lines as string in C. Something like this:
>
> 3 Hey Hello How are you?

Which is obviously "Too Broad". But now the question has changed and code has been added but not enough to identify the problem. It would now most likely be closed as "off-topic because Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior ..."

I have seen cases where 4 close votes go into under the too broad category. But then  a change is made, a final vote goes in for the off topic category, but it will still be closed under too broad, which is no longer correct.

**Should you be able to change your close vote reason if an edit to the question has been made?**

Comment: Yes. I'm sure this will have been requested years ago though and still not implemented.

Comment: Any edit to a question after you flag it automatically makes your flag disputed, correct? Does it not work the same way with close votes?

Comment: @BSMP Close votes are there unless you revoke them

Comment: @TinyGiant Or they age away, if it takes too long to close.

Comment: And if you revoke it you can't re-cast it. Being able to change it would be nice, if for example it went from unclear to dupe.

Comment: Check this [Why can't we change our close-vote reason?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262657/why-cant-we-change-our-close-vote-reason?rq=1) and this [Why can't we vote to close a question after the original vote was retracted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254778/why-cant-we-vote-to-close-a-question-after-the-original-vote-was-retracted)

Answer (score 42):

> Should you be able to change your close vote reason if an edit to the question has been made?

IMO, yes, yes this should be possible.

The main case for this that I see is if something is too broad, unclear, questions seeking debugging help then more details/code/error messages are added to make the question more clear and/or specific but it is a dupe. I've run across this quite a bit and, unless you get a dupe hammer wielding member to close as a dupe, it may get an extreme amount of redundant answers (especially on the "simpler" or more common questions).

Another use I have seen is, say, I close something as a dupe. The OP comments and explains why it isn't a dupe of the target (or edits and adds that to the post). OK, now it *isn't* a dupe of the original target but it *is* a dupe of another post. It would be nice to be able to change that VTC to a different, more relevant, target. This would help others to see the *real* dupe link without having to look through exhaustive comments or wait for it to be reopened.

For this to happen and be effective, I think there would need to be restrictions, obviously. A rep limit on retracting and recasting a close vote would be appropriate. If a member has a dupe hammer in their pocket and closes with that then they should be able to reopen and close (or just change the dupe target).

These are just a few thoughts I've had brewing on the topic for a little while. But there would need to be more consideration, I'm sure.

Comment: I only tend to fix the wrong dupe case where the regulars in the  [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room can help.

Comment: I agree that closing as duplicate (and what the duplicate question is) is the real issue here. Whether a question is closed as “too broad” or “off-topic” is less important in my opinion. The reasons have a fair amount of overlap anyway.

Comment: @5gon12eder sure some of those reasons have some overlap and aren't as important as a dupe being closed as a correct dupe. But, it is still nice that those others are closed for the correct reasons, otherwise, people get confused on why something is closed as "too broad" when it is really unclear. Such cases can just lead to more meta traffic and confusion on what is and what isn't appropriate and why.

Comment: @5gon12eder Incorrect close reasons can also lead to reopen votes from the review queue that may not be warranted. eg. A post closed as unclear gets made clear, but is still too broad. May be reopened if someone doesn't consider how broad the question is and mainly votes to disagree with the "unclear" closing.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those "nice to have" not "need to have" situations.

In an ideal world,
yes you would be able to change it.

However, there are several reasons why changing it is problematic.

First, there is a lot of systemic protection involved in close votes, such as totals for the day, making sure more than one close vote isn't cast per question, and counts for the close vote reason once the question was closed. These three aspects have a decent amount of structure that would be effected by changing close votes.

Second, from the standpoint that *questions are evaluated as encountered*, casting a close vote which is accurate when viewed is perfectly fine if applicable. Just like casting a down vote is. If the question changes to fix the issue, the vote can be removed if so inclined but the reality is that the question should have been on topic or site appropriate on first draft. That the question was changed over time while you wait to finally not be matching the chosen close vote or downvote may mean it has a future going forward, but it still doesn't change the fact that when encountered it warranted a downvote and a close vote.

There are millions of users here, and having multiple users wait just for one to *maybe* fix something doesn't always work and is disrespectful of those users who wait in the situations where nothing was fixed.