# Proposal: Allow high-rep users (or gold badge holders) to VTC again with a different reason

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, privileges, retracted-close-votes

I just had the following situation:

1. I read a question with missing information.
2. I vote-to-close for missing information and add a comment asking for that information.
3. OP adds that information.
4. I retract my vote.
5. Based on that information, I help the OP find the typo in their code.
6. I want to vote-to-close as "typo", but can't, since I had already submitted a close vote.

Related questions:

- [This related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254778/87698) explains why this restriction is in place ("preventing close wars").
- [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262657/87698) suggests being allowed to change the close vote reason. It [was rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262932/87698) three years ago by Shog9 because the simplest implementation of it (allowing people to retract and VTC again) would allow misuse (e.g. prevent vote aging).

I propose to re-consider adding this feature *for users who have proven themselves trustworthy* (e.g. for high-rep users or gold-badge tag holders), because

- the current status quo prevents volunteers from moderating who *want* to moderate and know how to moderate, and
- raising the requirements for doing it (e.g. high-rep or gold-badge) would prevent misuse of this feature in most of the cases.

Comment: I sort of agree with Shog9, since preventing abuse is important. I'd be more in favour of being able to change one's vote, not cast another one.

Comment: Changing Votes has been discussed on the Uber meta before: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/ability-to-change-close-reason-before-it-gets-closed and I agree that it is a worthwhile idea rather than retracting and revoting.

Comment: I thought all high rep golden badge holders befriend each other and can simply poke someone else to make him cast the new vote. But honestly, why high rep should be more differrent? When I retract my vote.. I can't vote anymore. Period. And you can? Unfair! My rights are.. you know.. harmed!

Comment: Instead, I recommend to read edited questions very carefully before retracting a close vote.

Comment: @TylerH This had nothing to do with reading the Q carefully though. The post fell under both close reasons separately at different times, making a revote seem like a valid tool in this specific case.

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes, it does. If OP read the edited question before removing their vote, they would have seen that the question is now likely caused by a typo, and would have known not to remove their close vote. This is under the policy of "don't reopen a question closed for the wrong reason just to close it again for the right reason".

Comment: @TylerH: To be honest, I don't like that policy. Call me petty, but it bothers me to see "Heinzi ... closed this question for reason X", when "reason X" does not apply to the question (any more).

Comment: @Heinzi I agree it is imperfect, but we can't have unlimited vote options because it leads to vote wars, so it is the best path forward until we get the option to adjust what close vote we use as psubsee2003 mentioned

Comment: @TylerH: I understand that. I'm not advocating unlimited vote options, but just being allowed to re-cast a *retracted* vote. I don't yet see how that could lead to vote wars (although I do acknowledge the problem with vote aging).

Comment: What should be the time-to-live on the re-cast vote? A vote normally live for 14 days or so. What if it's retracted on day 13 and re-cast. How long should it live?

Comment: While this can be annoying, I've personally stopped caring about this issue after taking the stance that, I'm not the only moderator that will see the problem.  Other moderators are just as capable of properly closing a question, after I have retracted a no longer valid close reason.

Comment: @Taplar Do you frequent low-traffic tags where only a few curators monitor the posts?