# How should I update the link I used for marking a question as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support

The problem seems to be very basic but I couldn't find an answer to it even after searching extensively. I saw a question on SO and found that It's a duplicate of another question so decided to cast 'Close Vote' on it. While doing so I selected the reason as duplicate but I accidentally provided a wrong link. Now, when I click again, the dialog opens but there's no way to update the link. Is there anyway I can do that?

I even tried to go for flagging as a dupe but that doesn't show up either and If I retract my vote, I won't be able to cast close vote on it again. So what's the way to approach it?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot change your vote. You can only retract it or keep it. If the vote is *completely* wrong, I'd suggest retracting it and posting in the comments the correct one. If it's just not the best dupe, you can keep your vote but ask in a comment for people to vote for another target. Your choice. Keeping the vote means the question would be closed faster, so if there is no benefit from keeping it open, then leaving the vote is probably OK.

Comment: Also worth noting that *retracting* the close vote, still leaves the automatically generated comment. The two are not linked. You can retract the vote and keep the comment or delete the comment and keep the vote, if you wish. *usually* it's not really worth it but occasionally I've retracted a dupe vote and kept the comment because it's still a useful signpost.

Comment: Oops, I meant [I voted to close with the wrong duplicate. What should I do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252403/215552) :-)

Comment: @VLAZ certainly those are some very useful tips. Will follow them.